# std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, g++, enable-if

I am trying to get a simple example to work to understand how to use `std::enable_if`. After I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627651/enable-if-method-specialization/6627748#6627748), I thought it shouldn't be too hard to come up with a simple example. I want to use `std::enable_if` to choose between two member-functions and allow only one of them to be used.

Unfortunately, the following doesn't compile with gcc 4.7 and after hours and hours of trying I am asking you guys what my mistake is.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template< class T >
class Y {

    public:
        template < typename = typename std::enable_if< true >::type >
        T foo() {
            return 10;
        }
        template < typename = typename std::enable_if< false >::type >
        T foo() {
            return 10;
        }

};


int main() {
    Y< double > y;

    std::cout << y.foo() << std::endl;
}
```

gcc reports the following problems:

```
% LANG=C make CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x" enable_if
g++ -std=c++0x    enable_if.cpp   -o enable_if
enable_if.cpp:12:65: error: `type' in `struct std::enable_if<false>' does not name a type
enable_if.cpp:13:15: error: `template<class T> template<class> T Y::foo()' cannot be overloaded
enable_if.cpp:9:15: error: with `template<class T> template<class> T Y::foo()'
```

Why doesn't g++ delete the wrong instantiation for the second member function? According to the standard, `std::enable_if< bool, T = void >::type` only exists when the boolean template parameter is true. But why doesn't g++ consider this as SFINAE? I think that the overloading error message comes from the problem that g++ doesn't delete the second member function and believes that this should be an overload.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it's the following: enable_if is based on SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error). However, you don't have any substitution here, because no parameter can't be used to determine which overload to use. You should make the "true" und "false" depend on T. (I know you did not want to do it in the simple example, but it's probably too simple now...)

Comment: I thought of that too and tried to use `std::is_same< T, int >::value` and `! std::is_same< T, int >::value` which gives the same result.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

SFINAE only works if substitution in argument deduction of a template argument makes the construct ill-formed. There is no such substitution.

> I thought of that too and tried to use `std::is_same< T, int >::value` and `! std::is_same< T, int >::value` which gives the same result.

That's because when the class template is instantiated (which happens when you create an object of type `Y<int>` among other cases), it instantiates all its member declarations (not necessarily their definitions/bodies!). Among them are also its member templates. Note that `T` is known then, and `!std::is_same< T, int >::value` yields false. So it will create a class `Y<int>` which contains

```
class Y<int> {
    public:
        /* instantiated from
        template < typename = typename std::enable_if< 
          std::is_same< T, int >::value >::type >
        T foo() {
            return 10;
        }
        */

        template < typename = typename std::enable_if< true >::type >
        int foo();

        /* instantiated from

        template < typename = typename std::enable_if< 
          ! std::is_same< T, int >::value >::type >
        T foo() {
            return 10;
        }
        */

        template < typename = typename std::enable_if< false >::type >
        int foo();
};
```

The `std::enable_if<false>::type` accesses a non-existing type, so that declaration is ill-formed. And thus your program is invalid.

You need to make the member templates' `enable_if` depend on a parameter of the member template itself. Then the declarations are valid, because the whole type is still dependent. When you try to call one of them, argument deduction for their template arguments happen and SFINAE happens as expected. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892087/if-the-address-of-a-function-can-not-be-resolved-during-deduction-is-it-sfinae-o) and the corresponding answer on how to do that.

Comment: ... Just to clarify, in case it's useful: When an instance of the `Y` template class is instantiated, the compiler will not actually compile the template member functions; however, the compiler WILL perform the substitution of `T` into the member template DECLARATIONS so that these member templates can be instantiated at a later time.  This point of failure is not SFINAE, because SFINAE only applies when determining the set of possible functions for *overload resolution*, and instantiating a class is not a case of determining a set of functions for overload resolution.  (Or so I think!)

Answer (score 119):

I made this short example which also works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class foo;
class bar;

template<class T>
struct is_bar
{
    template<class Q = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, bar>::value, bool>::type check()
    {
        return true;
    }

    template<class Q = T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Q, bar>::value, bool>::type check()
    {
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    is_bar<foo> foo_is_bar;
    is_bar<bar> bar_is_bar;
    if (!foo_is_bar.check() && bar_is_bar.check())
        std::cout << "It works!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment if you want me to elaborate. I think the code is more or less self-explanatory, but then again I made it so I might be wrong :)

You can see it in action [here](http://cpp.sh/7eccz).

Comment: This doesn't compile on VS2012. `error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I only tested it on with gcc. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17543296/660982

Comment: Why there is a need to create another template class `Q`, even though it is equal to `T`?

Comment: Because you need to template the `test` member function. Both cannot exist at the same time. `Q` just forwards the class template type `T`.
You could remove the class template `T` like so: http://cpp.sh/4nxw but that kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: What happens when you omit `= T` and leave it in form `template<class Q>`? I've tried it and nothing changes (as far as I can see).

Comment: @jpihl I believe in your last example referenced in the comments line 26 needs to read `if (!check_foo.test<foo>() && check_bar.test<bar>())`

Comment: @user1556435 if you don't mind me asking, why do you think that? My idea idea is to use the class template as a default for the member function template so that you don't need to specify the type when calling test() :)

Comment: ow, sorry I wasn't very clear, I was talking about your later example in the comments, on cpp.sh/4nxw I get syntax errors otherwise: `26:23: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token ...`. Did I misconfigure something? Anyway, your examples have helped me :)

Comment: Ah, I see.. When I re-read your comment is quiet clear what you meant. I must have been tired, thanks for your correction. I'm glad my example was of some value to you. I can't update the original comment, but for what it's worth, here's the updated example with @user1556435's correction: http://cpp.sh/7l4n

Comment: If you're stuck with C++ < 11 (as in my case, Eigen core library development), you also can't use default template arguments (as in VS2012). There's a workaround for that. Leave out the default template argument, and instead add a `Q*` argument to your function specializations. Then create a new function which calls these adapted functions, passing them an additional argument of `Q*` type, e.g. `(Q*)NULL`. See it here: http://cpp.sh/3d6uj (don't forget to check the C++98 compiler option).

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I really dislike that the API has to change. Now a user has to consider providing the method invocation with a template parameter; e.g. `bar_is_bar.check<foo>()` etc. (which is `false`).

Comment: If what you mean is that it would be better if you couldn't provide the template
to the "check()" function I agree.

Comment: I think while this works in real compilers, it violates the standard when there's no valid substitution. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26634553/5267751 .

Comment: @user202729 In what case would there not be a valid substitution?

Comment: Okay, I was wrong, in this case it's possible to pass suitable `Q` to both to make the specification valid. — As long as the user doesn't intentionally workaround that (by passing explicit value for `Q`) it's okay. (can also write a wrapper/proxy function)

Answer (score 19):

For those late-comers that are looking for a solution that "just works":

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template< typename T >
class Y {

    template< bool cond, typename U >
    using resolvedType  = typename std::enable_if< cond, U >::type; 

    public:
        template< typename U = T > 
        resolvedType< true, U > foo() {
            return 11;
        }
        template< typename U = T >
        resolvedType< false, U > foo() {
            return 12;
        }

};


int main() {
    Y< double > y;

    std::cout << y.foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ -std=gnu++14 test.cpp
```

Running gives:

```
./a.out 
11
```

Comment: Um, why would you rename `std::enable_if_t` to `resolvedType`.

Comment: Because not everyone can use C++17 for reasons that can vary widely.

Comment: Isn't this answer identical to [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21464113/5267751) anyway. (also see the comment below for possible standard violation)

Answer (score 12):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055923/stdenable-if-parameter-vs-template-parameter/11056319#11056319) post:

> Default template arguments are not part of the signature of a template

But one can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    template < class T,
               class std::enable_if < !std::is_integral<T>::value, int >::type = 0 >
    void f(const T& value)
    {
        std::cout << "Not int" << std::endl;
    }

    template<class T,
             class std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
    void f(const T& value)
    {
        std::cout << "Int" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.f(1);
    foo.f(1.1);

    // Output:
    // Int
    // Not int
}
```

Comment: It works, but this is basically templating functions, not the class itself... It does not allows dropping one of two identically-prototyped functions neither (when you need to pass over overloading). However, the idea is nice. Could you rewrite the OP example in a working form, please?

Comment: This just fails for me; anyway use `typename` instead of `class` at certain places (according to the linked answer) works. (unless you're using some unusual compiler version?)

Answer (score 6):

One way to solve this problem, specialization of member functions is to put the specialization into another class, then inherit from that class. You may have to change the order of inheritence to get access to all of the other underlying data but this technique does work.

```
template< class T, bool condition> struct FooImpl;
template<class T> struct FooImpl<T, true> {
T foo() { return 10; }
};

template<class T> struct FoolImpl<T,false> {
T foo() { return 5; }
};

template< class T >
class Y : public FooImpl<T, boost::is_integer<T> > // whatever your test is goes here.
{
public:
    typedef FooImpl<T, boost::is_integer<T> > inherited;

    // you will need to use "inherited::" if you want to name any of the 
    // members of those inherited classes.
};
```

The disadvantage of this technique is that if you need to test a lot of different things for different member functions you'll have to make a class for each one, and chain it in the inheritence tree. This is true for accessing common data members.

Ex:

```
template<class T, bool condition> class Goo;
// repeat pattern above.

template<class T, bool condition>
class Foo<T, true> : public Goo<T, boost::test<T> > {
public:
    typedef Goo<T, boost::test<T> > inherited:
    // etc. etc.
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The boolean needs to depend on the template parameter being deduced. So an easy way to fix is to use a default boolean parameter:

```
template< class T >
class Y {

    public:
        template < bool EnableBool = true, typename = typename std::enable_if<( std::is_same<T, double>::value && EnableBool )>::type >
        T foo() {
            return 10;
        }

};
```

However, this won't work if you want to overload the member function. Instead, its best to use [`TICK_MEMBER_REQUIRES`](http://pfultz2.github.io/Tick/doc/html/requires/#tick_member_requires) from the [Tick](https://github.com/pfultz2/Tick) library:

```
template< class T >
class Y {

    public:
        TICK_MEMBER_REQUIRES(std::is_same<T, double>::value)
        T foo() {
            return 10;
        }

        TICK_MEMBER_REQUIRES(!std::is_same<T, double>::value)
        T foo() {
            return 10;
        }

};
```

You can also implement your own member requires macro like this(just in case you don't want to use another library):

```
template<long N>
struct requires_enum
{
    enum class type
    {
        none,
        all       
    };
};


#define MEMBER_REQUIRES(...) \
typename requires_enum<__LINE__>::type PrivateRequiresEnum ## __LINE__ = requires_enum<__LINE__>::type::none, \
class=typename std::enable_if<((PrivateRequiresEnum ## __LINE__ == requires_enum<__LINE__>::type::none) && (__VA_ARGS__))>::type
```

Comment: It didn't work for me that way. Maaybe something is missing? Could you rewrite the OP example in a working form, please?

Comment: The original example doesn't work with overloading. I updated my answer how you can do it with overloading.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that both declarations of `foo()` differ in nothing but the default template arguments, and that doesn't make them separate declarations.
Defining the second `foo()` is just re-defining the first `foo()`.

Here is a summary of options, from most modern to least modern:

#### Conditionally compile member function with `requires` clause [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)

```cpp
T foo() requires some_condition<T> {
    return 10;
}

// Trailing requires clause could also be omitted here because the first 
// function is more constrained, and overload resolution will prefer it.
T foo() requires (!some_condition<T>) {
    return 5;
}
```

#### Workaround: select implementation with if constexpr [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)

```cpp
// This can only be used to select an implementation, not to make foo()
// disappear entirely.
T foo() {
    if constexpr (some_condition<T>) {
        // If this part more complex, you can put it in a private member function.
        return 10;
    }
    else {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

#### Proper use of `std::enable_if` [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)

```cpp
// note: Unfortunately, we pollute the function signature with additional template
//       parameters.
// note: std::enable_if_t can be used in C++14
// note: The additional U parameter is necessary to make the condition dependent
//       on a template parameter; otherwise the compiler will simply emit an error
//       for some_condition<T>.
template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<some_condition<U>, int>::type = 0>
T foo() {
    return 10;
}

template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<!some_condition<U>, int>::type = 0>
T foo() {
    return 5;
}
```

#### Alternative style for `std::enable_if` [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)

```cpp
// do SFINAE in trailing return type
template <typename U = T>
auto foo()
  -> typename std::enable_if<some_condition<U>, T>::type {
    return 10;
}

// do SFINAE in regular return type
template <typename U = T>
typename std::enable_if<!some_condition<U>, T>::type
foo() {
    return 5;
}
```

#### Mixins [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98)

```cpp
template <typename T, bool B>
struct mixin;

template <typename T>
struct mixin<T, true> {
    T foo() { return 10; }
};

template <typename T>
struct mixin<T, false> {
    T foo() { return 5; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Y : mixin<T, some_condition<T>> {};
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my minimalist example, using a macro.
Use double brackets `enable_if((...))` when using more complex expressions.

```
template<bool b, std::enable_if_t<b, int> = 0>
using helper_enable_if = int;

#define enable_if(value) typename = helper_enable_if<value>

struct Test
{
     template<enable_if(false)>
     void run();
}
```

Comment: I understand why you'd want that, but it's not idiomatic. We should be encouraging people to avoid macros and just write `template <typename = std::enable_if_t<b, int> = 0>`

Comment: @Ben Do you mean `template <bool b, std::enable_if_t<b, int> = 0>`?
I think using "requires" these days is a lot nicer though, and gets rid of dumb macros like this one.

Comment: probably. C++20 concepts can't come soon enough. :-/

Answer (score -1):

```
// Try this one:

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// suppose you want to disable certain member functions based on the tag
struct FooTag;
struct BarTag;

// macro to save some typings in the following
// note that a dummy typename is involved in both the 
// first and second parameters. 
// this should be different than the template parameter of the class (typename T for Widget below)

#define EnableIfFoo(T) \
template <typename Dummy = void, typename = \
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<FooTag, T>::value, Dummy>::type>

#define EnableIfBar(T) \
template <typename Dummy = void, typename = \
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<BarTag, T>::value, Dummy>::type>

template <typename T>
class Widget {
public:
    // enable this function only if the tag is Bar
    EnableIfFoo(T)
    void print() const { std::cout << "I am a Foo!" << std::endl; }
    
    // enable this function only if the tag is Foo
    EnableIfBar(T)
    void display() const { std::cout << "I am a Bar!" << std::endl; }
};


int main() {
    
    // instantiate a widget with tag Foo
    // only print is enabled; display is not
    Widget<FooTag> fw;
    fw.print();
    //fw.display(); // compile error !!
    
    // instantiate a Widget using tag Bar
    // only display is enabled; print is not
    Widget<BarTag> bw;
    bw.display();
    //bw.print(); // compile error !!
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).