# Specializing a class template method for derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'd appreciate help specializing the method `doIt()` in the following bit of code for classes that share a common base class, as shown below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

struct BarBase {};
struct Bar: BarBase {};

struct FooBase {};
struct Foo: FooBase {};

template <typename T>
struct Task
{
    // I'd like to specialize this method for classes with a common base class
    void doIt();        
};

// my attempt (does not compile)
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_base_of<FooBase, T> >::value
doIt() {
    std::cout << "Type is derived from FooBase\n";
}


int main()
{
    Task<Foo> f;
    f.doIt();
}
```

Comment: I think you cannot specialize class template member functions, you have to specialize the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specialise a template class member. You can specialise a class, and every specialisation is a complete separate class that inherits nothing from the unspecialised template (it may or may not have all or some of the members of the unspecialised class).

What you can also do is have a template member function in a template class, and specialise that. So you can do this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Task
{
    void doIt() { doItPriv<T>(); }
private:
    template<typename T1>
    void doItPriv();  
};
```

and then specialise `doItPriv`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function) answer,

> SFINAE only works if substitution in argument deduction of a template
>   argument makes the construct ill-formed.

That is why you cannot do smth like that:

```
template <typename T>
struct Task
{
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<FooBase, T>::value>::type doIt() {
        std::cout << "Type is derived from FooBase\n";
    }   

    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<FooBase, T>::value == false>::type doIt()
    {
    }
};
```

Here `doIt()` isn't template, so no any deduction.
But you can do the following:

```
template <typename T1>
struct Task
{
    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<FooBase, T>::value>::type doIt_() {
        std::cout << "Type is derived from FooBase\n";
    }   

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<FooBase, T>::value == false>::type doIt_()
    {
    }

    void doIt()
    {
        doIt_<T1>();
    }
};
```