# Why this SFINAE snippet is not working in g++, but working in MSVC?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

In MSVC2017 this works fine, both static_asserts are NOT triggered as expected:

```
template <typename T>
struct do_have_size {
    template <typename = decltype(std::declval<T>().size())>
    static std::true_type check(T);
    static std::false_type check(...);
    using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
};

int main() {
    using TR = typename do_have_size<std::vector<int>>::type;
    using FL = typename do_have_size<int>::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<TR, std::true_type>::value, "TRUE");
    static_assert(std::is_same<FL, std::false_type>::value, "FALSE");
}
```

However, if I compile in g++7.1 or clang 4.0 I get following compiler error:

```
In instantiation of 'struct do_have_size<int>':
20:39:   required from here
9:24: error: request for member 'size' in 'declval<do_have_size<int>::TP>()', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

From my understanding of SFINAE, substition of `true_type` returning function should fail for `int` parameter and next function shall be chosen, like it is done in MSVC. Why clang and g++ are not compiling it at all?

I've compiled with `-std=c++17` switch only, maybe something more is needed?

Comment: If you are using C++17, why ask about C++11.

Comment: I can't figure out for certain whether `is_detected` made it into C++17.  If so, seems like that would be perfect for this.  And even if not, the implementation of `std::experimental::is_detected` at cppreference.com should make it easy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with whether default template arguments are part of a function template's signature.

The real problem is that `T` is a class template parameter, and when you instantiate the class template's definition, the implementation can immediately substitute it into your default template argument, `decltype(std::declval<T>().size())` outside of template argument deduction, which causes a hard error if `size` is not present.

The fix is simple; simply make it depend on a parameter of the function template.

```
template <typename U, typename = decltype(std::declval<U>().size())>
static std::true_type check(U);
```

(There are other problems with your implementation, such as it requires a move-constructible non-abstract `T` and doesn't require `size()` to be const-callable, but they aren't the cause of the error you are seeing.)

Answer (score 24):

SFINAE doesn't work here, as the class is already instantiated with `T = int` in `do_have_size<int>::type`. SFINAE works only for a list of template function candidates, in your case you'll get a hard error since in the instantiation

```
do_have_size<int>::type
```

the member function

```
template <typename = decltype(std::declval<int>().size())>
static std::true_type check(T);
```

is surely ill-formed for `int`. The

```
static std::false_type check(...);
```

won't ever be considered. So gcc is right here in rejecting your code and MSVC2017 should not accept the code.

Related: [std::enable_if : parameter vs template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11055923/3093378) and [SFINAE working in return type but not as template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15427667/3093378)

**One solution** is to use the magic of [`void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) (since C++17, but you can define your own in C++11/14), which maps any type list to `void` and enables crazy simple-looking SFINAE techniques, like so

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<typename...>
using void_t = void; // that's how void_t is defined in C++17

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_size : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_size<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().size())>>
    : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    using TR = typename has_size<std::vector<int>>::type;
    using FL = typename has_size<int>::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<TR, std::true_type>::value, "TRUE");
    static_assert(std::is_same<FL, std::false_type>::value, "FALSE");
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Wandbox</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XWkzvHDbQL6GUMOi)

[**Here**](https://youtu.be/a0FliKwcwXE?t=29m7s) is a Cppcon video by Walter Brown which explains the `void_t` techniques in great detail, I highly recommend it!

Comment: /sigh. "hence SFINAE won't work in this case, in other words, there's no substitution/discarding going on" is just nonsense.

Comment: @T.C I realized it was misleading, happy now?

Comment: "default template arguments are not part of the function signature" still has nothing to do with OP's problem, and the suggested fix with `is_fundamental` is neither here nor there: it doesn't check for `size` at all, and it is completely unnecessary if the check is done properly.

Comment: @T.C Finally fixed.

Comment: You never get to the `check` call; the error happens as soon as the class template's definition is instantiated.

Comment: @T.C. Darn... ok, fixed again :)

Answer (score 5):

@vsoftco answered "gcc is right to reject your code".  I agree.

To fix, I say do this:

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

This is a `can_apply` library that makes this kind of SFINAE simple.

Now writing one of these traits is as simple as:

```
template<class T>
using dot_size_r = decltype( std::declval<T>().size() );

template<class T>
using has_dot_size = can_apply< dot_size_r, T >;
```

test code:

```
int main() {
  static_assert( has_dot_size<std::vector<int>>{}, "TRUE" );
  static_assert( !has_dot_size<int>{}, "FALSE" );
}
```

Live example.

In C++17 you can move over to less declval filled expressions.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

template<class F>
constexpr auto can_invoke(F&&) {
  return [](auto&&...args) {
    return std::is_invocable< F(decltype(args)...) >{};
  };
}
```

`can_invoke` takes a function `f` and returns a "invokation tester".  The invokation tester takes arguments, then returns `true_type` if those arguments would be valid to pass to `f`, and `false_type` otherwise.

`RETURNS` makes it easy to make a single-statement lambda SFINAE friendly.  And in C++17, the lambda's operations are constexpr if possible (which is why we need C++17 here).

Then, this gives us:

```
template<class T>
constexpr auto can_dot_size(T&& t) {
  return can_invoke([](auto&& x) RETURNS(x.size()))(t);
}
```

Now, often we are doing this because we want to call `.size()` if possible, and otherwise return 0.

```
template<class T, class A, class...Bs>
decltype(auto) call_first_valid(T&& t, A&& a, Bs&&...bs) {
  if constexpr( can_invoke(std::forward<A>(a))(std::forward<T>(t)) ) {
    return std::forward<A>(a)(std::forward<T>(t));
  else
    return call_first_valid(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Bs>(bs)...);
}
```

now we can

```
template<class T>
std::size_t size_at_least( T&& t ) {
  return call_first_valid( std::forward<T>(t),
    [](auto&& t) RETURNS(t.size()),
    [](auto&&)->std::size_t { return 0; }
  );
}
```

As it happens, @Barry has proposed a feature in C++20 that replaces `[](auto&& f) RETURNS(f.size())` with `[](auto&& f)=>f.size()` (and more).

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by using [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to SFINAE away the template version of check based on either the parameter or the return type. The condition I used was [std::is_fundamental](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental) to exclude int, float and other non-class types from instantiating the template. I used the `-std=c++1z` flag to clang and gcc. I expect `-std=c++14` should work too.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct do_have_size {
    static std::false_type check(...);

    template <typename U = T, typename = decltype(std::declval<U>().size())>
    static std::true_type check(std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<U>::value, U>);

    // OR
    //template <typename U = T, typename = decltype(std::declval<U>().size())>
    //static auto check(U)
    //    -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<U>::value, std::true_type>;

    using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
};

int main() {
    using TR = typename do_have_size<std::vector<int>>::type;
    using FL = typename do_have_size<int>::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<TR, std::true_type>::value, "TRUE");    
    static_assert(std::is_same<FL, std::false_type>::value, "FALSE");
}
```