# using template aliases combined with partial specialization of templates

Tags: c++, templates, alias, sfinae

I am banging my head around why the following leads to a compile error.
I am a novice in meta programming but to my understanding of SFINAE principle the following functions are mutually exclusive hence it is not a 'redefinition' of an existing function.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using IsNotEnum = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value>::type;

template<typename T>
using IsEnum = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type;

template<typename T, typename = IsNotEnum<T>>
void doSomething()
{
}

template<typename T, typename = IsEnum<T>>
void doSomething()
{
}
```

g++ 7.5 complains with followings:

```
error: redefinition of ‘template<class T, class> void doSomething()’
void doSomething()
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
note: ‘template<class T, class> void doSomething()’ previously declared here
void doSomething()
```

Comment: See [common mistake with enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305222/default-template-argument-when-using-stdenable-if-as-templ-param-why-ok-wit/38305320#38305320)

Comment: This reminds me of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055923/stdenable-if-parameter-vs-template-parameter/51659883#51659883)

Comment: Default arguments are not part of the function signature.

Answer (score 2):

Try rewriting your function as follows

```
template<typename T, IsNotEnum<T> = nullptr>
void doSomething()
{
}

template<typename T, IsEnum<T> = nullptr>
void doSomething()
{
}
```

and your `using`s as follows

```
template <typename T>
using IsNotEnum = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value, std::nullptr_t>::type;

template <typename T>
using IsEnum = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::nullptr_t>::type;
```

or simply, if you have a C++14 or more recent compiler,

```
template <typename T>
using IsNotEnum = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum<T>::value, std::nullptr_t>;

template <typename T>
using IsEnum = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::nullptr_t>;
```

The problem in your code is that you can't write two different functions differing only for a template default type/value.

So, removing the default value, SFINAE doens't disable the unwanted function. So you have a function collision.

Only removing the type (on the left of the equal sign) SFINAE remove the unwanted function.

Comment: nice, I didn't realize the "typename =" is a default type assignment. With that piece of info it makes perfectly sense. Thanks