# Would a static nested bool help me disable a call for certain types or is there a cleaner way?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have a template class, say:

```
template<class T>
class someClient
{
void someCallbackA() {foo_->onA();}
void someCallbackB() {foo_->onB();}

private:
T* foo_;
};
```

which I can instantiate with a bunch of different types T which support the `onA` and `onB` interface. I happen to have a case where two out of the several different types `T` I use needs a particular behavior controlled from `someClient` so I need to add some function `doBar()` to these two types (call them `Edge1` and `Edge2`). Then I want a part of the `someClient` code to call `foo_->doBar()` but without breaking when the type of `foo_` does not have that. Is there a way to use `boost::enable_if` to have a `someClient::doBar()` which will call `foo_->doBar()` only for those two types, but not be there, or expand to nothing if the types are not `Edge1` or `Edge2`?

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
template <class T, enable_if<mpl_or<is_same<T,Edge1>, is_same<T,Edge2> > >
someClient<T>::doBar() {foo_->doBar();}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. I used C++11 `<type_traits>` instead of boost's:

```
struct Edge {
    void doBar() { std::cout << "did Bar."; }
};

template<typename T>
class someClient
{
public:

    template<typename U = T>
    typename
    std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, Edge>::value, void>::type
    doBar() { foo_->doBar(); }

    template<typename U = T>
    void doBar( typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, Edge>::value, void>::type* = 0 )
    { /* do nothing */ }


private:
    T* foo_;
};

int main()
{
    someClient<int> i;
    someClient<Edge> e;
    i.doBar();
    e.doBar();  // outputs "did Bar."
}
```

`doBar()` needs to be template itself for this to work, explanation here: [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function)

Comment: So you need the U so as to have SFINAE happen when I say i.doBar() via deduction? If i used T instead of U, SomeClient<int> or SomeClient<Edge> would have invalid instantiations of their definitions and wouldn't compile?

Comment: Oh and, for the empty version, why can't you just have a general template which does nothing? like template<typename U = T> void doBar() {} instead of having to specifically say it's the member template for the case of "not Edge"?

Comment: Because that would be a second definition which, I think, violates ODR rule.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pull any special tricks at all if you just don't *call* member functions that don't make sense. Template member functions are only specialized when needed (unless you add an explicit specialization). So the following code works fine:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    void do_foo() { p->foo(); }
    void do_bar() { p->bar(); }
    T * p;
};

struct A { void foo() {} };

int main()
{
    A a;
    Foo<A> x = { &a };
    x.do_foo();
}
```

The fact that `Foo<A>::do_bar` wouldn't compile is not an issue, since the member function is never instantiated. And `p->bar` isn't a compiler error, because `p` has a dependent type and the line is thus only parsed in the second lookup phase (which never happens).

Comment: But what if he *needs* to call do_bar() in every instantiation, even if there's no `A::bar()`?

Comment: @jrok: You could specialize `Foo<T>::do_bar` for certain types, or use another trait further in...