# C++ Nesting SFINAE Template Produces Compilation Error

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm trying to create an addition operator for a custom template class, where the first argument is allowed to be either an instance of my class or a basic numeric type.  My operator has a definition similar to the example code below:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct MyTemplateStruct {
    T val;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct MyCommonType {
    typedef std::common_type_t<T, U> type;
};
template<typename T, typename U>
using MyCommonTypeT = typename MyCommonType<T, U>::type;

template<typename T, typename U>
MyTemplateStruct<MyCommonTypeT<T, U>> operator +(
    MyTemplateStruct<T> const& a, MyTemplateStruct<U> const& b)
{
    return { a.val + b.val };
}

template<typename T, typename U>
MyTemplateStruct<MyCommonTypeT<T, U>> operator +(
    T const a, MyTemplateStruct<U> const& b)
{
    return { a + b.val };
}

int main()
{
    MyTemplateStruct<double> a{ 0 }, b{ 0 };
    a = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

My expectation was that due to SFINAE, the compilation error that results from trying to instantiate the second operator definition with `T = MyTemplateStruct<double>, U = double` would just exclude that template from the list of potential matches.  However, when I compile, I'm getting the following error:

> /usr/include/c++/7/type_traits: In substitution of ‘template<class ... _Tp> using common_type_t = typename std::common_type::type [with _Tp = {MyTemplateStruct, double}]’:
> main.cpp:18:38:   required from ‘struct MyCommonType<MyTemplateStruct, double>’
> main.cpp:31:39:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, class U> MyTemplateStruct<typename MyCommonType<T, U>::type> operator+(T, const MyTemplateStruct&) [with T = MyTemplateStruct; U = double]’
> main.cpp:40:13:   required from here
> /usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:2484:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::common_type, double>’

If I directly utilize `std::common_type_t` in the operator definition, instead of using my wrapper template `MyCommonTypeT`, then SFINAE works as I expect and there is no error.  How can I make the above code compile when I have to wrap the call to `std::common_type` in another template?

Comment: Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550980/whats-wrong-with-my-sfinae-testing-supported-operators?rq=1), it appears I may need to add a template that takes the value `true_type`/`false_type` depending on whether my template accepts the provided template parameters.  Then, declare my struct to take a defaulted parameter indicating whether the types T/U are supported, and only provide the `typedef` when they are.  Seems kind of kludgy, but it may work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `MyCommonTypeT<T, U>` (i.e. `MyCommonType<T, U>::type`) itself invalid, it's not enough that `std::common_type_t<T, U>` is invalid when declaring `type` in `MyCommonType`. For example you can specialize `MyCommonType`, when `MyTemplateStruct` is specified as template argument, `type` is not declared.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct MyCommonType {
    typedef std::common_type_t<T, U> type;
};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct MyCommonType<MyTemplateStruct<T>, U> {};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct MyCommonType<T, MyTemplateStruct<U>> {};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/92tBtJMph0FF5bVy)

Comment: By doing this, I have to explicitly disable the template for each type I want to use it with.  Is there a way to instead enable it only when types `T` and `U` pass `std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && std::is_arithmetic_v<U>`?  I've seen code where people just add a defaulted template parameter, but didn't know if that is the best way forward.  E.g., `template<typename T, typename U, bool=std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && std::is_arithmetic_v<U>>` that is empty, then overload it when the third parameter is true with the `typedef`.

Comment: @JeffG https://wandbox.org/permlink/LvUusJcqTuThmAmW

Comment: I did like that you moved the default parameter into the template specialization, so users can't lie about whether they are numeric.  However, is there a reason that you used the `typename` version instead of `bool`?  I find the typename version more difficult to read.  E.g., what is the advantage over `template<typename T, typename U, bool=false> struct MyCommonType {};`, then `template<typename T, typename U> struct MyCommonType<T, U, std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && std::is_arithmetic_v<U>> { typedef std::common_type_t<T, U> type; };`?

Comment: Asked and answered; the version I proposed in my previous comment doesn't compile.

Comment: @JeffG It seems the type of specialized non-type template argument can't depend on a template parameter.