# The usage of enable_if in non-templated member functions of class templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enable-if

I am trying to define a class template with non-templated member function `f()`,
where f() is allowed to call only when the template agument of the class is `int`.

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    T f()
    {
        typename enable_if< is_same<T,int>::value >::type();

        return 0;
    };
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> x;

    MyClass<double> y;

    x.f();
    y.f(); // generates compile-time error
}
```

It works, but is it a good idea, or it is better to use the regular solutions ?

[std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function)

[usage of enable_if for non-templated member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088830/usage-of-enable-if-for-non-templated-member-function)

[Selecting a member function using different enable_if conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401716/selecting-a-member-function-using-different-enable-if-conditions)

Are there alternative methods ?

**[EDIT]**

The problem is that if I use the standard technique, the templated function call via `y.f<int>()` will be allowed in the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    template<typename U = T>
    typename enable_if< is_same<U,int>::value, T >::type f()
    {
        T a = 1;

        return a;
    };

};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> x;

    MyClass<double> y;

    x.f();
    y.f<int>();   // does not generate compile-time error
    y.f();        // generates compile-time error
}
```

Comment: `static_assert(is_same<T,int>{}, "not an int!");`. enable_if is not for *causing compiler errors*, it's for controlling the overload resolution procedure by resulting in a substitution failure in an immediate context

Comment: @PiotrS.: You should make than answer, otherwise somebody will flag this as `NotAComment`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error

Comment: Murphy, Machiavelli, and all that. Someone crafty enough to write `y.f<int>()` is probably crafty enough to work out other ways to foil your plans.

Comment: @PiotrS. I added a supplementation to the question.