# Restriction of access to function

Tags: c++, c++11, traits, type-traits

I have a generic class with a function that I want to restrict to instances of floating point types only, at compile time. As shown in the example below:

```
template <typename T>
class ClassName
{
    // instance variables, etc..

    void some_method()
    {
        // do stuff, but only for floating point types
    }
}
```

How do I make the compiler reject the usage of some_method for ClassName of non-floating point types?

I have been looking at SFINAE but I simply can't get it to work, so after several hours of failing I'm asking for your help.

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried? You could probably put something together with [`std::is_floating_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) and [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: Currently I'm wrapping the function in another function like so:
`void some_other_method() { some_method(std::is_floating_point<T>()); }`
`void some_method() { }`
This works, but I would like a solution where I don't have to wrap the function.

Comment: @juanchopanza You can make your example work if you make `some_method` a template, though. I'm looking for a previous answer that explains the mechanisms at stake here.

Comment: Template specialization is a valid technique to achieve this too.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I fixed my example, but in the meantime it seems others have arrived at the same solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `std::is_floating_point` and `std::enable_if` to only enable the function for floating point types:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class ClassName
{
    // instance variables, etc..
 public:
  template<typename T2 = T,
           typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point<T2>::value >::type>
  void some_method()
  { 
    // do stuff, but only for floating point types
  } 
};

int main()
{
  ClassName<double> d; // OK
  d.some_method();     // OK
  ClassName<int> i;    // OK
  i.some_method();     // ERROR
}
```

Comment: @PetrBudnik was first, but this answer is more elaborate, thus accepted. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Use static_assert, if your compiler support c++11

```
void some_method()
{
    static_assert( std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "Only for floating points" );
    // do stuff, but only for floating point types
}
```

Then there will be compiler error if you try call this method for non floating points parameter.

And for not-floating point:

```
static_assert( !std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "and only for non-floating point" );
```

Comment: You need to negate the condition.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
template< typename Tdummy = T, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point< Tdummy >::value >::type >
 void some_method()
{
}
```

EDIT to elaborate. This will result in the following. Compiler will generate `some_method()` only for `ClassName` with floating-point template parameter. It will not be generated for non-floating types and will result in a compile-time error.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class ClassName
{
    // instance variables, etc..
    template< typename Tdummy = T, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point< Tdummy >::value >::type >
    void some_method()
    {
        // do stuff, but only for floating point types
    }

 void some_general_method
  {
   // general stuff for all types
  }
};

int main()
{
 ClassName< float > bar;
 ClassName< int > foo;

 bar.some_general_method(); // OK
 foo.some_general_method(); // OK

 bar.some_method(); // OK
 foo.some_method(); // Compile-time ERROR 

 return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Will T in this template == T in the class template?

Comment: @Jesper Just make it default type. I was giving general idea. See Edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
void some_method(){

    if (std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
    {
        // do stuff, but only for floating point types
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I tried with `boost::is_floating_point` too :-

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_floating_point.hpp>

template <typename T>
class ClassName {
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_floating_point<T> >::type
some_method(const T & t)
{

}
};

int main()
{
ClassName<float> p; //Compiles

/* Following throws error, 
error: no type named 'type' in 
    'struct boost::enable_if<boost::is_floating_point<int>, void>'
ClassName<int> q;
*/
}
```

Comment: Not quite the same. Note "How do I make *the compiler reject* the usage of some_method for ClassName of non-floating point types?".

Comment: @Mgetz yes there is a solution (see other answers). You can get the same results that the proposed `static if` can achieve without having it. You can quote me on that.

Comment: @Mgetz no, it does not. Functions definitions are not instantiated unless used. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=46f36b442ad191ec5bb171388773d46d-6bd941bd569898d6f94f2545382ce976, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bb47a5533c53dc8a49441d51bcfaef8c-6bd941bd569898d6f94f2545382ce976, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a520465ed8ca7d7c84237dd3450542ec-6bd941bd569898d6f94f2545382ce976, and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8482aeca87df479ac97193bf36b7dbd4-6bd941bd569898d6f94f2545382ce976 as examples.

Answer (score 1):

[As detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972771/923854), you need the member function to be a template for SFINAE to work ([Live example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=615dbc9ce7593a160baf0252d02392a6-e1204655eaff68246b392dc70c5a32c9)):

```
template <typename T>
class ClassName
{
    // instance variables, etc..

public:
    template <typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
    void some_method()
    {
        // do stuff, but only for floating point types
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** per R. Martinho Fernandes comment

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct ClassName
{
    // instance variables, etc..

    template<typename R = T>
    void some_method()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_floating_point<R>::value,
            "ClassName<T>::some_method is implemented only for floating "
                "point T");
        // do stuff, but only for floating point types
    }
};

int main()
{   
    ClassName<float> f;
    f.some_method();
    ClassName<int> i;
    i.some_method(); // <-- static_asserts here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's SFINAE for if you are going to assert the opposite of the enabling condition?

Comment: When SFINAE picks the *non*-floating-point-T variant, which is supposed to barf, then I assert that R(=T) *is* floating point. So it barfs.

Comment: Sure, but it also barfs if you just put the assert in the function without any SFINAE.