# Type-dependent range-based inserter function

Tags: c++, iterator

I would like to maintain a range-based and type-dependent method for insertion in my class.

The question is how you can implement this type-dependency by using iterators.

The following pseudo code should explain my problem:

```
class Test {

public:
    template<typename Iterator>
    void insert(const uint8 position, const Iterator begin, const Iterator end) {
        std::copy(begin, end, std::inserter(m_deque, m_deque.begin());
    }


private:
    std::deque<uint8> m_deque;

};


int main() {

    Test t;

    uint8 dataone[] = {0x00, 0xff};
    uint16 datatwo[] = {0xff, 0x00};
    std::vector<uint8> vecdataone = {0x00, 0xff};
    std::vector<uint16> vecdatatwo = {0xff, 0x00};

    t.insert(0, dataone, dataone + 2); // OKAY
    t.insert(0, datatwo, datatwo + 2); // SHOULD CAUSE AN ERROR
    t.insert(0, vecdataone.cbegin(), vecdataone.cend()); // OKAY
    t.insert(0, vecdatatwo.cbegin(), vecdatatwo.cend()); // SHOULD CAUSE AN ERROR

}
```

Greets.

Comment: You're saying you want it to compile **only if** the type of `position` is the same as the `value_type`?

Comment: Nope. The underlying type of the input iterator should be the same as the `value_type` of my `m_deque`.

Comment: why the `const Iterator` in the parameter list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static assertion will do the job:

```
void insert(const uint8 position, const Iterator begin, const Iterator end)
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type,
            uint8_t
        >::value,
        "Need iterators to uint8_t!"
    );
    // ....
}
```

I'd also suggest to use `deque`'s own insert function instead of `std::copy`:

```
 m_deque.insert(s.deque.begin() + position, begin, end);
```

Being a member function and thus aware of internals, it can do a better job at optimizing the insertion.

Comment: Great thanks. I will try this. But is there also another way maybe like this: `template<typename Iterator<uint8>> insert(...)`?

Comment: @SteveMurdock There are other ways, like for example the technique used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function), but nothing as straightforward as that (it would at least require a fair amount of boilerplate code to get close to the syntax you want). Not worth it, IMO.

Comment: +1 for the mentioning of the member insert (as also mentioned in Effective STL). Since you use `static_assert`, you might as well use the other C++11 feature of `decltype(*begin)` instead of the longer traits extraction.

Comment: @TemplateRex `decltype(*begin)` could be a const or non-const ref, so that doesn't buy us much.

Answer (score 1):

I like (and upvoted) jrok's answer, but here's another approach using SFINAE, which means you can potentially allow matching to some other `insert` overrides if that makes sense.  Error messages may be more cryptic than for jrok's answer though.

```
template<typename Iterator>
typename std::enable_if<
             std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type,
                          uint8>::value,
             void>::type 
insert(const uint8 position, const Iterator begin, const Iterator end)
    ...
```

demo at http://ideone.com/c1d9jT