# Template specialization with compile time constant

Tags: c++, templates, atl

I am trying to build a specialization for a template class with a compile time constant.

The template class looks like this:

```
template<class TNativeItem, class TComItem = void,
         VARTYPE _vartype = _ATL_AutomationType<TComItem>::type>
class InOutComArray
{
private:
    CComSafeArray<TComItem, _vartype> _safeArray;
    // ...
public:
    InOutComArray(
        TNativeItem* items, size_t length,
        std::function<TComItem(const TNativeItem&)> convertToCom,
        std::function<TNativeItem(const TComItem&)> convertFromCom)
        : _safeArray(length)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```

Usage would be for example:

```
InOutComArray<BOOL, VARIANT_BOOL, VT_BOOL>(
    items, length, BOOLToVARIANT_BOOL, VARIANT_BOOLToBOOL));
```

However, there also exist types that don't require conversion and I wanted to provide a short hand version for this:

```
InOutComArray<LONG>(items, length);
```

I tried to implement it like this:

```
template<class TItem, VARTYPE _vartype = _ATL_AutomationType<TItem>::type>
class InOutComArray<TItem, void, _vartype>
    : public InOutComArray<TItem, TItem, _vartype>
{
public:
    InOutComArray(TItem* items, size_t length)
        : InOutComArray<TItem, TItem, _vartype>(
              items, length, NoConverter<TItem>, NoConverter<TItem>)
    {

    }
};
```

However, I get the following error:

> '_vartype' : default template arguments not allowed on a partial specialization

Is there any way around that?

Comment: The error message is quite clear.

Comment: @40two And your comment not helpful. I was specifically asking about a way *around* that error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first define the default arguments to be `void` and `_ATL_AutomationType<TComItem>::type`, so when exactly one argument X is given, you want `InOutComArray<X>` to be an `InOutComArray<X, void, _ATL_AutomationType<void>::type>`.

Your partial specialization contradicts this: `InOutComArray<X>` shall be a `InOutComArray<X, X, _ATL_AutomationType<X>::type>`.

Depending on what you thik will be more likely second argument, (i.e. `void` or the same as the first argument), you could make the second argument defaulted to the first one in the first place:

```
template<class TNativeItem, class TComItem = TNativeItem,
     VARTYPE _vartype = _ATL_AutomationType<TComItem>::type>
```

That way the behavior of the partial specialization is covered, except for the additional constructor. This can be achieved by using default arguments for the constructor:

```
template<class TNativeItem, class TComItem = TNativeItem,
     VARTYPE _vartype = _ATL_AutomationType<TComItem>::type>
class InOutComArray
{
public:
InOutComArray(
    TNativeItem* items, size_t length,
    std::function<TComItem(const TNativeItem&)> convertToCom = NoConverter<TNativeItem>(),
    std::function<TNativeItem(const TComItem&)> convertFromCom = NoConverter<TNativeItem>());
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this excellent information! This looks very elegant, however, the following scenario isn't solved by this: `InOutComArray<LONG, VT_I8>(items, length)`. Is there a way to allow this?

Comment: The `std::enable_if` doesn't seem to work, I am getting `'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,size_t>'`. [Looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function) it can't be used like this?

Comment: An `InOutComArray<LONG, VT_I8>` would be an `InOutComArray<LONG, VT_I8, _ATL_AutomationType<VT_I8>::type>` - I guess that is not what you want? (No idea what VT_I8 might be) If you are looking to "overload" the second template parameter, so you can have either a TComItem or a VARTYPE (whatever that might be). I am not sure if that is possible at all - you will have to specify all the arguments in one of the cases.

Comment: What I meant by that was that I can write `InOutComArray<LONG, VT_I8>` and get a `InOutComArray<LONG, LONG, VT_I8>`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: corrected the enable_if part, it's not needed. As for your last comment: you can resolve a `InOutComArray<X, Y>` either to `InOutComArray<X, Y, _ATL_AutomationType<Y>::type>` or to `InOutComArray<X, X, Y>`, but not sometimes the former and sometimes the latter. You seem to want both - you will have to decide.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard *§14.5.5/8 Class template partial specializations [temp.class.spec]:*

> *The template parameter list of a specialization shall not contain default template argument values.*

Thus, the compiler rightfully complains because in your partial specialization you give default template argument value for `VARTYPE _vartype = _ATL_AutomationType<TItem>::type`.

Comment: Thanks for the details about your comment. But I wasn't really asking if the compiler was right.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way around that?

Yes, remove the default template argument from the partial specialization. You don't need it.

Per the primary template:

```
template<class TNativeItem, class TComItem = void,
         VARTYPE _vartype = _ATL_AutomationType<TComItem>::type>
class InOutComArray
```

These types are equivalent:

```
InOutComArray<LONG>
InOutComArray<LONG, void, _ATL_AutomationType<TComItem>::type>
```

And whenever `InOutComArray` is instantiated with `TComItem = void`, you will get the partial specialization:

```
template<class TItem, VARTYPE _vartype>
class InOutComArray<TItem, void, _vartype>
```

Comment: Ha, indeed. However, the following scenario isn't solved by this: `InOutComArray<LONG, VT_I8>(items, length)`. Is there a way to allow this?

Comment: That's not something that can be solved by specialization. A specialization doesn't introduce another way of providing template arguments.