# How to conditionally add a function to a class template?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have a Matrix class template as follows:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t nrows, std::size_t ncols>
class Matrix
{
    T data[nrows][ncols];
public:
    T& operator ()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
    {
        return data[i][j];
    }
};
```

What I want is to define a `.setIdentity()` function only for instantiations when `nrows==ncols` is `true` at compile time. And there will be **no** definition of `.setIdentity()` when `nrows==ncols` is `false`.

What I am trying is using `enable_if` idiom, but that will define the function for all cases. Isn't it?

Comment: Maybe instead of mutating existing objects conditionally, you just have a static function like `make_identity<typename T, std::size_t N>` that returns a `Matrix<T, N, N>`.

Comment: @GManNickG: Favorite solution so far (because it's the simplest!). Please consider adding it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ templates: conditionally enabled member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633239/c-templates-conditionally-enabled-member-function)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it with `std::enable_if` in the following mode

```
template <std::size_t r = nrows, std::size_t c = ncols>
typename std::enable_if<r == c>::type setIdentity ()
 { /* do something */ }
```

A full example

```
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T, std::size_t nrows, std::size_t ncols>
class Matrix
{
    T data[nrows][ncols];

public:
    T& operator ()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
    { return data[i][j]; }

    template <std::size_t r = nrows, std::size_t c = ncols>
    typename std::enable_if<r == c>::type setIdentity ()
     { /* do something */ }
};

int main()
 {
   Matrix<int, 3, 3>  mi3;
   Matrix<int, 3, 2>  mnoi;

   mi3.setIdentity();
   // mnoi.setIdentity(); error

  return 0;
}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

As pointed in a comment by Niall (regarding the TemplateRex's answer, but my solution suffer from the same defect) this solution can be circonvented expliciting the number of rows and columns in this way

```
mi3.setIdentity<4, 4>();
```

(but this isn't a real problem (IMHO) because `mi3` is a square matrix and `setIdentity()` could work with real dimensions (`nrows` and `ncols`)) or even with

```
mnoi.setIdentity<4, 4>()
```

(and this is a big problem (IMHO) because `mnoi` isn't a square matrix).

Obviously there is the solution proposed by Niall (add a `static_assert`; something like

```
    template <std::size_t r = nrows, std::size_t c = ncols>
    typename std::enable_if<r == c>::type setIdentity ()
     {
       static_assert(r == nrows && c == ncols, "no square matrix");

       /* do something else */ 
     }
```

or something similar) but I propose to add the same check in `std::enable_if`.

I mean

```
template <std::size_t r = nrows, std::size_t c = ncols>
typename std::enable_if<    (r == c)
                         && (r == nrows)
                         && (c == ncols)>::type setIdentity ()
 { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: should guard against `mi3.setidentity<4,4>()`

Comment: @TemplateRex - thanks for reporting the problem; answer modified.

Comment: Yes, the guard is cleaner ibside the enable_if, error from clang is quite informative, +1

Comment: The circumvention problem can be solved by adding a `typename ...` before the template parameters.  Template parameter packs will be deduced as empty in normal cases, and the user can't supply the other parameters explicitly anymore.

Comment: @L.F. - Wow! Your solution is very elegant. And works. But I don't understand how, exactly, works. I mean... I see that writing `mnoi.setIdentity<3u, 3u>();`, or also `mnoi.setIdentity<int, long, 3u, 3u>();`, gives a compilation error. But why you can't explicate arguments after a variadic pack if the arguments are differents? I mean... can you say what part of the standard forbid this?

Comment: @max66 I didn't really think of that :D I guess there's some rule like "arguments can't be supplied after a pack," but I'll need to dig into the standard further to find out.

Comment: @L.F. - Maybe a little less elegant... but writing `template <std::size_t..., std::size_t r = nrows, std::size_t c = ncols>` avoid the circumvent problem because if you explicit some `std::size_t` they are adsorbed in the unnamed `std::size_t...` pack. Drawback (?): no compilation error.

Comment: Why do we need `r` and `c` (or something)? e.g.
`template <std::size_t foo = 123>`
`typename std::enable_if<(nrows == ncols) && foo == 123>::type setIdentity ()`

Answer (score 10):

### The lazy and needlessly repetitive way

Just add a partial specialization:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class Matrix<T, N, N>
{
    T data[N][N];
public:
    T& operator ()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
    {
        return data[i][j];
    }

    void setidentity(/*whatever params*/) { std::cout << "yay!"; }
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1ce7d00e6b83ccf)

For general `N * M` matrices, the general template will be instantiated, whereas only for `N * N` matrics, this specialization is a better match.

Disadvantage: code repetition of all regular code. Could use a base class, but it's actually easier to do some SFINAE magic (below)

### A slightly harder but more economical way

You can also use SFINAE by adding hidden template parameters `N` and `M` that default to `nrows` and `ncols` to `setidentity`, and to `enable_if` on the condition `N == M`.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t nrows, std::size_t ncols>
class Matrix
{
    T data[nrows][ncols];
public:
    T& operator ()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
    {
        return data[i][j];
    }

    template <std::size_t N = nrows, std::size_t M = ncols, std::enable_if_t<(N == M)>* = nullptr>
    void setidentity(/*whatever params*/) { 
        static_assert(N == nrows && M == ncols, "invalid");
        std::cout << "yay!"; 
    }
};
```

Or, since the question was tagged C++11, use `typename std::enable_if<(N == M)>::type` instead.

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a692a3942a48e68)

Comment: This solution seems to repeat all the existing work the non-special case has already done. Is it really worth the repetition?

Comment: This requires implementing the entire class twice.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Your 2nd code doesn't seem to compile even  `m22.setidentity()` line. See my link [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTEdSZERtMkFVdHc). I need it to be `C++11` compatible, seems you have used GCC 6.1.0 version.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TemplateRex: actually even with your newer solution for C++11, link [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMb3JvRUtpN0p4ems). See the link, it gives `error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'`.

Comment: @smlq thanks for noticing this, I fixed it. The problem was that the template parameters of `setidentity` need to be used in the `enable_if` condition. Now it should work. You can still apply the `typename ::type` for C++11, [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21b0db6a5b8b1365)

Comment: I might add a `static_assert( N == nrows && M == ncols, "invalid");` to the `setidentity` to avoid silly client behaviour like; `Matrix<int, 3,3> sq; sq.setidentity<4,4>();`

Answer (score 7):

Use a pseudo-CRTP to add modular support for something.

```
template<class T, std::size_t nrows, std::size_t ncols>
class Matrix;

template<class T, std::size_t size>
struct MatrixDiagonalSupport {
  auto self() { return static_cast<Matrix<T, size, size>*>(this); }
  auto self() const { return static_cast<Matrix<T, size, size> const*>(this); }
  void setIdentity() {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      for (std::size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        (*self())(i,j) = {};
      }
      (*self())(i,i) = 1; // hope T supports this!
      for (std::size_t j = i+1; j < size; ++j) {
        (*self())(i,j) = {};
      }
    }
  }
};
template<class T>
struct empty_t {};
template<bool b, class T>
using maybe= std::conditional_t<b, T, empty_t<T>>;

template<typename T, std::size_t nrows, std::size_t ncols>
class Matrix: public maybe<nrows==ncols,MatrixDiagonalSupport<T, nrows>>
{
  // ...
```

Here we inherit from nothing if we aren't diagonal, and a class implementing set identity if we are diagonal.

Users of `Matrix` get `.setIdentity()` from its parent magically if it is right.

`static_cast` inside `self()` ends up being a zero-cost abstraction and giving the base class access to the child class.

This is pseudo-CRTP because we don't actually pass the derived class type to the parent, just enough information for the parent to reconstruct it.

This solution makes the method an actual method, and avoids any kind of SFINAE trickery.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b422c9555e07fa4)

In C++11 replace `conditional_t<?>` with `typename conditional<?>::type`:

```
template<bool b, class T>
using maybe=typename std::conditional<b, T, empty_t<T>>::type;
```

and everything should compile.

Comment: cute idea, but the `empty_t` needs to be tagged in case there are multiple modules to support

Comment: @template `maybe` written to make that seamless.

Comment: @Yakk: Would this usage be called a mixin? (seems so to me...)

Comment: @matt no idea what pattern is called.  Sorry.  Even patterns I use all the time I often get the name wrong.

Comment: @Yakk: Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't `setIdentity` complain of undefined reference to `operator()` because it is actually defined way down in the source file? And couldn't this `static_cast` be considered UB?

Comment: @JoaoBapt I'm sorry, I don't have a source file in my example, so I'm not sure what you are talking about.  As for the static cast, no, you can do a downcast so long as the object types actually match; if you get it wrong, it is UB.

Comment: `(*self())(i,i)` calls `Matrix::operator()`, which is only really declared/defined after `MatrixDiagonalSupport` is defined. I’m afraid this might cause undefined reference errors.

Comment: @JoaoBapt No, it won't.  The CRTP is a common, well known template strategy in C++.  If you have questions about how the CRTP works, google it, and if that doesn't work, [ask a question] using the stack overflow interface.

Answer (score 6):

A basic, but simple solution not mentioned by any other answer: you can use `std::conditional` and inheritance.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<cstddef>

struct HasSetIdentity {
    void setIdentity() { }
};

struct HasNotSetIdentity {};

template<typename T, std::size_t nrows, std::size_t ncols>
class Matrix: public std::conditional<(nrows==ncols), HasSetIdentity, HasNotSetIdentity>::type
{
    T data[nrows][ncols];
public:
    T& operator ()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
    {
        return data[i][j];
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix<int, 2,2> m1;
    m1.setIdentity();
    Matrix<int, 2,3> m2;
    // Method not available
    // m2.setIdentity();
}
```

You can still move data down the hierarchy if you need them to be shared by all the subobjects.
It mostly depends on the real problem.

Comment: @skypkack: Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is cleanest, most idiomatic approach of all given here I think.

Answer (score 1):

[skypjack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39155452/4296393) and [max66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154242/4296393) have both presented simple answers to the problem. This is just an alternate way of doing it, using simple inheritance, although it means the use of a child class for square matrices:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t nrows, std::size_t ncols>
class Matrix
{
protected:
    T data[nrows][ncols];
public:
    T& operator ()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
    {
        return data[i][j];
    }
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class SqMatrix : public Matrix <T, N, N>
{
public:
    setIdentity()
    {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```