# add function member to a template class conditionally

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have a class template defined as follow

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
  T t_;
  // void f();
};
```

My question is how to add the f() method only if the type T is integer without compilation error.

```
int main()
{
  A<int> a; // OK
  A<string> b; // OK
}
```

Example :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T t;
    template <typename..., typename U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>> say_hello() { std::cout << "Hello"; }
};


int main()
{
    Foo<int>();
    Foo<double>();
}
```

```
Error   C2938   'std::enable_if_t<false,void>' : Failed to specialize alias template
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154014/how-to-conditionally-add-a-function-to-a-class-template

Comment: No, i will get a compilation error if I instanciate a class with a non integer type

Comment: No, I want to compile without error for every type

Comment: @Roger [Edit] the question to include a [mre] depicting the error then.  I don't get any compilation error: https://wandbox.org/permlink/M3k6VVQlmINT1CNU

Comment: No, the error message is failed to specialize alias template if I try to instanciate an object with double type

Comment: Make sure that you make `f` a function template and let your `enable_if_t` condition depend on a template parameter of the `f`, as I showed in the link.  Again, without a [mre], we have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Done, i attached the example with the error message

Comment: I made a mistake, it's work now. Thank you very much

Comment: It should be `std::is_same_v<U, int>`, not `std::is_same_v<T, int>`.

Comment: @Roger You are not going to accept any answers so perhaps this question should be removed?

Comment: Yes I accept L. F. Answer.

Comment: @L.F. F. did not leave an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable specific functions using `type_traits` and SFINAE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<U>, int> = 0>
    void f() {
        std::cout << "int " << t_ << '\n';
    }
private:
    T t_;
};


int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.f();

    A<std::string> s;
    // s.f(); //  error: no member named 'f' in 'A<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >'
}
```

If you have many integer specific functions you can put them in a class of its own and inherit that class only if `T` is integral.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Atype>
class int_functions {
public:
    Atype* This() { return static_cast<Atype*>(this); }

    void f() {
        std::cout << "int " << This()->t_ << '\n';
    }
};

template<typename Atype>
class non_int_functions {
};

template<typename T>
class A : public std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, int_functions<A<T>>,
                                                           non_int_functions<A<T>>>
{
    friend std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, int_functions<A<T>>,
                                                     non_int_functions<A<T>>>;
public:
private:
    T t_;
};
```

Comment: I don't have a special functions to integer type.its just one function. I try to avoid a copy paste of the code

Comment: @Roger Ok, added a simpler solution for that case. There wouldn't be any copy/pasting using my first suggestion though.