# Conditionally defining method for container class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

Is it possible (and is it a good idea) to conditionally define methods for some container class (`template<typename ThingType> class Container`) depending on the type of its elements? I first thought it was possible after reading about `std::enable_if`, but now I am not certain I understand.

Below is my attempt (click [here](https://ideone.com/IS4Jgv) to run on ideone). In the case that `std::is_base_of<ThingBase, ThingType>::value` is `false`, a return type for `p` will not be defined. I figured the compiler would just instantiate the object of a class without that method. But it turns out it doesn't compile.

Is there another tool for the job? Or should I write two `Container`-like classes that have different behavior depending on what `ThingType` is? Or maybe this is a job for a specialization.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>


class ThingBase {
public:
    virtual void printHi() = 0;
    
};

class Thing : public ThingBase
{
    void printHi(){
        std::cout << "hi\n";
    }   
};


template<typename ThingType>
class Container{
private:
    std::vector<ThingType> m_things;
public:

    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ThingBase, ThingType>::value>::type p()
    {
        m_things[0].printHi();
    };
};


int main() {
    
    //Container<Thing> stuff; // works!
    Container<int> stuff; // doesn't work :(
    
    return 0;
}
```

#### Edits:

The error message from the compiler is

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Container<int>’:
prog.cpp:36:17:   required from here
prog.cpp:26:78: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ThingBase, ThingType>::value>::type p()
```

[@StoryTeller - Unslander Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller-unslander-monica) I don't intend for this method to be overloaded. I want it to be available to the end user whenever it makes sense for it to be available. There will only be one of these `p` methods, and it should take only one (relatively simple) signature.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to also add the compiler error message here.

Comment: Is the method you seek to define meant to be overloaded? Will there be more than one `p`? Will this one have a unique signature?

Comment: Are you limited to C++11? C++20 has `requires` which can conveniently disable unneeded methods.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that sounds pretty awesome, but I better stick to c++11

Comment: For "how to do the question in title" see [C++ templates: conditionally enabled member function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633239/c-templates-conditionally-enabled-member-function) (although as the answer below pointed out, not necessary in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't intend for this method to be overloaded. I want it to be available to the end user whenever it makes sense for it to be available. There will only be one of these p methods, and it should take only one (relatively simple) signature.

This simplifies the exercise quite a bit. The solution is... to do nothing special.

```
void p() {
    m_things[0].printHi();
}
```

When a class template is implicitly instantiated, only the declarations of member function are instantiated along with it. Definitions are not instantiated until an attempt is made to use the member.

So you do not need to do anything special. The error will happen if it's used when it cannot be used.

If still you wish to ensure derivability, and produce a descriptive error in that case, you can add a `static_assert` to the member function body. Simply use the `is_base_of` test for a condition, and add a nice string to accompany it.

This is a common approach when writing generic utilities. SFINAE's primary purpose on the other hand is to control overload resolution. But you aren't doing it here.

Comment: This works for `int`, but what about a type that happens to have a `printHi` but is not derived from `ThingBase`? At least that's what I was assuming from "anytime it makes sense", and the `is_base_of`.

Comment: @cigien - *"but what about a type.."* What about it? If the OP doesn't want the extra genericity they can static assert, as I indicated. Either way, the use of SFINAE for case like this verges too much to a cargo cult.

Comment: Oh, right, you did mention the `static_assert`. And yeah, I agree, `enable_if` is overkill for this job.