# Use same template function for different arguments?

Tags: c++

If I have a complicated function that I want to use for two collections with matching interfaces (at least as far as the function in question is concerned) is there a way to just re-use the template code?

For example:

```
void DoSomethingIntense(std::vector<blah> myBlah);
void DoSomethingIntense(std::array<blah> myBlah);
```

If I use begin, end, size, and other functions that both array and vector have in common, is there a way to re-use the body of DoSomethingIntense without typing it twice (or, heaven forbid, stuffing it into a macro)?

(Please do not nitpick the example code, it doesn't help anybody)

UPDATE: My apologies, I neglected to mention that the function in question has other implementations for classes that do not match this signature; just making every argument use the code that works for these two is not an option.

I think the iterator solution might be best in that scenario.

Comment: Isn't a template function exactly what you need? I'm confused because your question contains the obvious answer...

Comment: This isn't a template function, but perhaps it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use a template.

```
template <typename Container>
void DoSomethingIntense(Container blah) {  // Might be better as Container const &
    // write code using blah.begin() or whatever
}
```

You might be able to make it even more generic, following the example of STL, by supporting a general iterator range rather than specifically a container:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void DoSomethingIntense(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve that by using templates:

```
template<typename T>
void DoSomethingIntense(const T &myBlah);
```

EDIT:

If I get your update right then I would say make use of [SFINEA](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
template<typename T>
struct is_vector : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename A>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_array : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct is_array<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type {};

// add more if you want or define a macro

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_vector<T>::value || is_array<T>::value, void>
DoSomethingIntense(const T &myBlah)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    DoSomethingIntense(v); // OK

    std::array<float, 5> a;
    DoSomethingIntense(a); // OK

    std::queue<int> q;
    DoSomethingIntense(q); // ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix templates / overloads. No problem.

For example:

```
template <typename T> 
void DoSomethingIntense(T myBlah) {

}

void DoSomethingIntense(MyCustomClass myBlah) {

}
```

Then it will use the non-template version for argument type `MyCustomClass` and the template version for anything else (like `vector` or `array`)

Moreover, you can use [std::enable_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/) to restrict the range of possible template arguments. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function).