# Conditionally include members in template class

Tags: templates, c++11

I would like to exclude or include some members in a template class, based on the value of its template parameter. Here's an example:

```
enum t_chooser {A, B, all};

template <t_chooser choice>
class C {

    // include if choice==A
    int v1;
    // include if choice==B
    long v2;
    // include if choice==B    
    int v3;
    // include for every value of choice
    bool v4;
};
```

If the template parameter `choice` is equal to `all`, all members should be included.
Is there a way to achieve this in C++11, maybe even using `std::enable_if`?

I have seen a solution for member functions here: [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function)

Comment: It would also be interesting to know, if it is possible to include / exclude lines of code in methods, where these variable are used, i.e. writing a method that works for all template values, similarly to an `#ifdef` macro.

Comment: you can TMP most things like this but you'll need helpers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you could specialize the entire `C` class for each type of `t_chooser` but that's a pain since you'd have to duplicate *everything*.  Instead you can put the specialization into a helper struct and then derive it in `C`

```
enum t_chooser {A, B, all};

template <t_chooser choice>
struct Vars; // undefined

template<>
struct Vars<A> { // just the A vars
  int v1;
};

template<>
struct Vars<B> { // just the B vars
  long v2;
  int v3;
};

template<>
struct Vars<all> : Vars<A>, Vars<B> { }; // derive both, get everything

template <t_chooser choice>
class C : private Vars<choice> { // or public if you want to expose them
    bool v4;
};
```