# Why SFINAE requires the 'Enable' class template parameter?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, sfinae, class-template

<sup>(this question is not related to C++11/C++14: the examples are compiled using C++03)</sup>

`enable_bool<T>` has a member `::type` only when `T` is `bool`

```
template <class T>
struct enable_bool
{};

template <>
struct enable_bool< bool >
{ typedef bool type; };
```

In the next snippet, the partial specialization is correct (see [gcc.godbolt.org](http://goo.gl/n4U4QL))

```
template <class T, class U, class Enable = T>
struct Foo
{
    static int bar() { return 0; }
};

template <class T, class U>
struct Foo< T, U, typename enable_bool<T>::type >
{
    static int bar() { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    return Foo <int, bool>::bar();
}
```

As `enable_bool<T>::type` already corresponds to `T` (when `T` is `bool`)
we are tempted to factorize parameters `T` and `Enable`.
But compiler complains (see [gcc.godbolt.org](http://goo.gl/XjDCpk))

```
template <class T, class U>
struct Foo
{
    static int bar() { return 0; }
};

template <class T, class U> //ERROR non-deducible template parameter 'T'
struct Foo< typename enable_bool<T>::type, U >
{
    static int bar() { return 1; }
};
```

**Why compiler cannot deduce template parameter `T` in this above partial specialization?**

Comment: Dupe. tl;dr: yes, it's "specified in the C++ standard" in that it's a fundamental fact of how `std::enable_if` actually works. No, it won't "evolve" in C++17.

Comment: Hi @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Thanks for your comment but question [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function) is not the same. In his answer, Johannes says *"`std::enable_if<>::type` accesses a non-existing type, so that declaration is ill-formed"*. This is maybe the answer of my question. I wonder about the C++ Standard/Compiler reason to do not allow one single parameter for SFINAE (using `std::enable_if` or not). Please reopen my question. Cheers

Comment: It is my way of informing you that this requirement is due to how `std::enable_if` works. Therefore, to answer the question, you should read how `std::enable_if` works; certainly there is little to gain in our repeating all of that here. I did actually read the answers there (albeit briefly), and confirmed that they make reference to this particular requirement, within the broader scope and context of the feature in question.

Comment: However, if you'd like to come back in a couple of days having studied that post, with _specific_ queries that relate to the information therein, I'd be happy to take another look.

Comment: Hi @LightnessRacesinOrbit. I have read questions/answers and `std::enable_if` documentation. But it is not obvious where the answer is. (Please give me the answer). I think it will not help SO users to be redirected to the other question (because the answer of my question is not blinking there). I have fully rewritten my question since first post. My question is not related to C++11 neither to `std::enable_if`. While rewriting/testing the code I got a light. I think the answer is because compiler needs to know where is the parameter `int`. If you reopen the question I can provide an answer.

Comment: The issue is unrelated to `enable_if`s implementation. Rather, the form of the pattern used in the partial specialization, `typename some_template<T>::type`, is specifically forbidden from deducing `T` by C++03[temp.deduct.type]p4. The rationale: You need the nested `::type` to match against the template argument, and finding that type requires instantiating *all* specializations of the template (and might be ambiguous, produce deep errors). There's no special rule for simple templates such as `enable_if`; and if there was, that would make `enable_if` useless.

Comment: Hi @dyp. Thanks for your comment. I have just fully reworked my question. Doing this simplification work (in my head and in SO) I realized that compiler cannot deduce `T` when trying to match `typename enable_bool<T>::type` and `int`. I agree: my question is not related to SFINAE. Do you want to provide an answer?

Comment: @olibre Well if you have come to this conclusion yourself, then I think there's no need for me to write an answer. But feel free to write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Finally the question was not even related to SFINAE!

Consider this very simple snippet without SFINAE:
`enable<T>::type` is always same as `T` whatever the provided `T` type.

```
template <class T>
struct enable
{ typedef T type; };       // Enable always

template <class U, class V>
struct Foo
{
    static int bar() { return 0; }
};

template <class X, class Y> //ERROR non-deducible parameter 'X'
struct Foo< typename enable<X>::type, Y >
{
    static int bar() { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    return Foo<int, bool>::bar();
}
```

When compiler tries to match `Foo<int, bool>` with `Foo<typename enable<X>::type,Y>`

- `1st param U = int  <--> enable<X>::type` => Cannot deduce `X`
- `2nd param V = bool <--> Y`

Compiler is not designed to deduce `X` from equation `int = enable<X>::type`.
Therefore, compiler needs some help from developer.
Another parameter is required: `Enable`.

The below fixed snippet add the `Enable` class template parameter.
The compiler performs the following matching:

- `1st param U     =int <--> X`
- `2nd param V     =bool<--> Y`
- `3rd param Enable=int <--> enable<X>::type` (deduced `X` from 1st param)
  <sup>(3rd param is `int` because declaration `class Enable=U` means *by default 3rd param same as 1st one*)</sup>

Fixed snippet:

```
template <class T>
struct enable
{ typedef T type; };       // Enable always

template <class U, class V, class Enable = U>
struct Foo
{
    static int bar() { return 0; }
};

template <class X, class Y> // Compiler can deduce 'X'
struct Foo< X, Y, typename enable<X>::type >
{
    static int bar() { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    return Foo<int, bool>::bar();
}
```