# Knocking out a class template constructor depending on class template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Given the following class template:

```
#include <type_traits>

template< class T, class Unrelated >
struct MyClass
{
    static_assert( std::is_same< T, char >::value ||
                   std::is_same< T, char16_t>::value ||
                   std::is_same< T, char32_t >::value,
                   "MyClass only defined for char, char16_t, char32_t" );
    MyClass( T init ) {}
    MyClass( char32_t init ) {}
    // ...
};
```

The second (`char32_t`) constructor is a special case for `T == char` and `T == char16_t`.

Obviously, it would generate an error for `T == char32_t`. So, I would like to "knock out" that constructor for that case. The class is rather large, with most of the code being shared for all `T`, so I would rather not specialize the whole class for the `char32_t` case.

I have seen [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) as well as related answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368) here on SO, but was unable to adapt any of the presented solutions / examples to my specific case (non-templated constructor in class template).

So I ask for your assistance:

**How to disable the `MyClass( char32_t )` constructor for `MyClass< T, U >` with `T == char32_t`?**

Alternatively, if that is easier, how to disable the `MyClass( T init )` constructor for `T == char32_t`? (For `char32_t`, the two constructors are functionally identical.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have seen enable_if as well as related answers like this one here on
>   SO, but was unable to adapt any of the presented solutions / examples
>   to my specific case (non-templated constructor in class template).

You have to make your constructor templated, using a default argument. Then make sure that `enable_if` depends on the default argument. Shortly:

```
//void_t trick made a type dependant
template<class T, class ... >
struct always
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<class T, class ... D>
using always_t = typename always<T, D...>::type;

template<class T, class Unreleated>
class MyClass
{
public:
    // ... 
    MyClass( T init ) 
    {
    }

    template<class U = void>
    MyClass( std::enable_if_t<
                !std::is_same<T, char32_t>::value,
                always_t<char32_t, U> //< enable_if expression depends on U
             > init)
   {
      //decltype(init) is always char32_t, but the compiler can not know that
   }
};
```

Try it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86cc4b071d03a4fc).

Comment: This is still technically ill-formed NDR if instantiated with a non-char32_t. No valid specialization can be generated for the constructor template (you aren't allowed to specialize enable_if, so enable_if<false, stuff>::type is always invalid).

Comment: @T.C. Would swapping `always_t<char32_t, U>` and`char32_t` in my code solve the issue?

Comment: Sure, or `class U = T`, and then always use `U` and not `T`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite the solution you've asked for, but it might solve the underlying problem.

You could implement your core functionality in `Base<T, Unrelated>` and then define:

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct MyClass : Base<T, U> {
    using Base::Base;
};

template <typename U> struct MyClass<char32_t, U> : Base<char32_t, U> {
    using Base::Base;

    MyClass(char32_t init) { /* your constructor here */ }
};
```

Comment: Isn't this the wrong way around? *Enabling* the `char32_t` constructor for `T == char32_t`?