# Reduce templated class arguments in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class like this:

```
template <unsigned int A, unsigned int B>
class Foo { ... };
```

Foo needs a method called bar(), but I need to specialise this. For a case, when A == B, I want it to do a thing, and something else otherwise. Can I do this without writing an if statement into the function? Like:

```
Foo<A, A>::bar() { ... } and Foo<A, B>::bar() { ... }
```

Comment: Partical class specialization doesn't help you?

Comment: Tag dispatching might help also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can partially specialize your class:

```
#include<cassert>

template<typename A, typename B>
struct S {
    void f(int i) { assert(i == 42); }
};

template<typename A>
struct S<A, A> {
    void f(int i) { assert(i == 0); }
};

int main() {
    S<int, double> s1;
    S<int, int> s2;
    s1.f(42);
    s2.f(0);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I could do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution to partial specialization is enable_if. I have assumed you have integer template parameters, but if you have types you can use `std::is_same<TA,TB>`.

This answer is based on solutions from here: [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function)

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/692fbfff1b9d84e8

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <unsigned int A, unsigned int B>
class Foo { 
    public:

        template<unsigned int TA=A, unsigned int TB=B>
        typename std::enable_if< TA == TB >::type
        bar() {
         std::cout << "equal version = " << A << "  " << B << "\n";
        }

        template<unsigned int TA=A, unsigned int TB=B>
        typename std::enable_if< TA != TB >::type
        bar() {
         std::cout << "NON equal version = " << A << "  " << B << "\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<1, 1> f1;
    f1.bar();

    Foo<1, 2> f2;
    f2.bar();    
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
equal version = 1  1
NON equal version = 1  2
```

Example for typed template parameters:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05d6a93480e870aa

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename A, typename B>
class Foo { 
    public:

        template<typename TA=A, typename TB=B>
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<TA, TB>::value>::type
        bar() {
         std::cout << "equal version" << "\n";
        }

        template<typename TA=A, typename TB=B>
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<TA, TB>::value>::type
        bar() {

         // This will cause compilation error if this bar() overload is to be instantiated
         // but since it is not there is no compilation error
         typename TA::non_exists ii = 0;
         std::cout << "NON equal version" << "\n";
        }
};
int main()
{
    Foo<int, int> f1;
    f1.bar();

    //Foo<int, float> f2;
    //f2.bar();    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I only have the equal version then only that gets declared?

Comment: @PeterLenkefi Only used functions should be instantiated by compiler