# C++ friend function template overloading and SFINAE different behaviors in clang++, g++, vc++ (C++14 mode)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sfinae, friend-function, function-templates

So, the following code builds and runs successfully under clang++ (3.8.0), but fails both under g++ (6.3.0) and vc++ (19.10.24903.0). Both g++ and vc++ complain about redefinition of operator&&.

Does anyone know which compiler is at fault here. For the compilers that fails to compile the code, what would be the workarounds for the compilation error?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct awaitable
{
    friend awaitable<void> operator&&(awaitable a1, awaitable a2)
    {
        std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable a1, awaitable a2) - T: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        return awaitable<void>{};
    }

    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, void>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    friend awaitable<void> operator&&(awaitable<void> a1, awaitable<U> a2)
    {
        std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable<void> a1, awaitable<U> a2) - U: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        return awaitable<void>{};
    }

    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, void>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    friend awaitable<void> operator&&(awaitable<U> a1, awaitable<void> a2)
    {
        std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable<U> a1, awaitable<void> a2) - U: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        return awaitable<void>{};
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    awaitable<int> a1, a2, a3, a4;
    auto ar = a1 && (a1 && a2) && (a2 && a3) && a4;
}
```

clang++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb01926bbcacdfb0

g++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73d17a5ae26f22eb

vc++: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SFINAE works at template instantiation level, i.e. at `struct awaitable<T>`, not at the level of individual members of the template. `awaitable<void>` is a valid instantiation and as such it instantiates the declarations of all 3 members of the class, duplicating the latter 2.

It is not that the two definitions conflict with each other - it is that each definition conflicts with itself ([example](http://rextester.com/XRLN87339)) ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function)).

**Workaround 1**

Define the helper operators out-of-class (granted, not exactly the same as what you had - these would be friends to *any* instance of the template)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct awaitable
{
    friend awaitable<void> operator&&(awaitable a1, awaitable a2)
    {
        std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable a1, awaitable a2) - T: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        return {};
    }

    template<typename U>
    friend std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value, awaitable<void>> operator&&(awaitable<void> a1, awaitable<U> a2);

    template<typename U>
    friend std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value, awaitable<void>> operator&&(awaitable<U> a1, awaitable<void> a2);

};

template<typename U>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value, awaitable<void>> operator&&(awaitable<void> a1, awaitable<U> a2)
{
    std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable<void> a1, awaitable<U> a2) - U: " << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
    return {};
}

template<typename U>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value, awaitable<void>> operator&&(awaitable<U> a1, awaitable<void> a2)
{
    std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable<U> a1, awaitable<void> a2) - U: " << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
    return {};
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    awaitable<int> a1, a2, a3, a4;
    auto ar = a1 && (a1 && a2) && (a2 && a3) && a4;
}
```

**Workaround 2**

Use no SFINAE at all, but a specialization of `awaitable`. Note the specialization is reversed - the base implementation is a special case for `awaitable<void>` and the specialization is for everything else.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, bool isvoid = std::is_void<T>::value>
struct awaitable
{
    friend awaitable<void> operator&&(awaitable a1, awaitable a2)
    {
        std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable a1, awaitable a2) - void" << std::endl;
        return {};
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct awaitable<T, false>
{
    friend awaitable<void> operator&&(awaitable a1, awaitable a2)
    {
        std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable a1, awaitable a2) - T: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        return {};
    }

    friend awaitable<void> operator&&(awaitable<void> a1, awaitable<T> a2)
    {
        std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable<void> a1, awaitable<T> a2) - U: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        return {};
    }

    friend awaitable<void> operator&&(awaitable<T> a1, awaitable<void> a2)
    {
        std::cout << "operator&&(awaitable<T> a1, awaitable<void> a2) - void" << std::endl;
        return {};
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    awaitable<int> a1, a2, a3, a4;
    auto ar = a1 && (a1 && a2) && (a2 && a3) && a4;
}
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to work around the compilation errors for both g++ and vc++! But behavior wise, did clang++ behave correctly or g++/vc++?

Comment: Added some more details.

Comment: So you mean that clang is the faulty one here by not preventing the conflicting definitions? Or, clang was able to somehow "merge" any conflicting definitions if they are *exactly* the same?

Comment: Refactored the answer. Yes, I think clang is wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for more details!