# C2995: template already defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfinae, friend

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729107/c-friend-function-template-overloading-and-sfinae-different-behaviors-in-clang) and its answer and still don't understand why I am encountering this issue.

This code compiles in VS2017:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
struct A
{
    template<class U>
    friend std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value, A<void>> operator&&(A<U> a1, A<void> a2)
#if 1
    ;
#else
    {
        return {};
    }
#endif

};

#if 1
template<class U>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value, A<void>> operator&&(A<U> a1, A<void> a2)
{
    return {};
}
#endif

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    A<int> a1;
    A<void> a2, a3;
    
    a3 = a1 && a2;
    
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit.\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

But if I change the `#if 1`s to `#if 0`s, I get C2995:  template function has already been defined.

Why does the compilation fail if I define the friend function inside `struct A` but succeed if I define it outside?

Comment: perhaps there is a "1" template already in the global?  Try changing the "1" to something unique and see if that gives the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a rule in the standard that says this is an error, from [[temp.inst.3]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#3):

> However, for the purpose of determining whether an instantiated redeclaration is valid according to [[basic.def.odr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) and [[class.mem]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem), a declaration that corresponds to a definition in the template is considered to be a definition.

Example from the standard:

```cpp
template<typename T> struct Friendly {
  template<typename U> friend int f(U) { return sizeof(T); }
};
Friendly<char> fc;
Friendly<float> ff;  // error: produces second definition of f(U)
```

In your example, `A<void>` is instantiated when the friend function is instantiated in the instantiation of `A<int>`. That generates the second definition of the friend function.