# Condition in class definition

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, conditional-statements

I'm trying to do something like:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

class B{}

template <class T>
class A
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> ptrVector;
    public:
        A<T>();
        void pushBack(std::shared_ptr<T> t);
        if(std::is_same<T, B>::value)
        {
            void doSth();
        }
        ~A<T>(){};
};
```

is it even possible to do a condition like this, somehow?
No, I can't inherit from this class, and need doSth() ONLY if `A<B>`, the doSth() should not exist if `A<C>`.

Comment: Note, `_B` is a generally reserved identifier. Avoid those.

Comment: On another (unrelated) note: you don't need the template when declaring the constructor or destructor. E.g. `A();` is just fine, the compiler will do the right thing anyway.

Comment: is `B` vs `_B` a typo or on purpose?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::enable_if` to conditionally make `doSth` available without having to specialize the entire class:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> ptrVector;
    public:
        A<T>();
        void pushBack(std::shared_ptr<T> t);    

        template <typename U = T>
        auto doSth() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, B>::value>;     

        ~A<T>(){};
};
```

You need `template <typename U = T>` because `std::enable_if_t` relies on SFINAE. See [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function) for more information.

Comment: Thats EXACTLY what i was looking for, thanks a lot <3

Comment: Interesting construction. Can you 1) explain the `->` construction a bit more, and 2) explain what `auto` does in this context?

Comment: @Chiel: `auto foo(...) -> R` is a *trailing return type*, introduced in C++11. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_trailing_return_types?lang=en

Comment: [hpp](https://hastebin.com/xijiqocupe.hpp) , [cpp](https://hastebin.com/uzokulepoz.cpp) , these are the files i wrote, but i keep getting error: prototype in .cpp doesn't match any in .h. How should it look?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a [full specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). e.g.

```
class B {};

template <class T>
class A
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> ptrVector;
    public:
        A();
        void pushBack(std::shared_ptr<T> t);
        ~A(){};
};

template <>
class A<B>
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> ptrVector;
    public:
        A();
        void pushBack(std::shared_ptr<B> t);
        void doSth();
        ~A(){};
};
```

You can also consider about making a common base class to avoid code duplication.