# A proper function declaration for conversion from ANSI string to std::basic_string<TCHAR>

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I tried to declare a function that converts **const char *** to **std::basic_string** in the following way:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <tchar.h>
#else
#define TCHAR char
#endif

typedef TCHAR Char;

typedef std::basic_string<Char> String;

template <typename = typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<Char, char>::value >::type >
inline String FromACString(const char * p_src)
{
    String dest(std::strlen(p_src), ' ');

    auto p_cur = p_src;

    for (auto & ch : dest)
    {
        ch = *p_cur++;
    }

    return dest;
}

template <typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<Char, char>::value >::type >
inline String FromACString(const char * p_src)
{
    return p_src;
}
```

but got compiler errors. My idea was to have two overloads and enable one of them depending on TCHAR type. What is the proper way to do this?

The error with VC2017 is:

```
error C2995: 'String FromACString(const char *)': function template has already been defined
```

Comment: What is `C` in `std::is_same<C, char>`? What compilation error did you get?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux C is Char, I corrected the code. The error with VC2017 is: error C2995: 'String FromACString(const char *)': function template has already been defined

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky add the error message to the question as well.

Comment: @user2079303 added.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function). `std::enable_if` only works if it depends on a function template's template arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. SFINAE only works in dependent contexts.  Since nothing in `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Char, char>::value>::type` is dependent on any template parameters, SFINAE does not apply, and you get a hard error since `std::enable_if<false>::type` is invalid.
2. When determining the "uniqueness" of templates, only the parameter types themselves are considered, not their default values.  You have two definitions of the function template `template <typename> String FromACString(const char*)`, and that is an error.

To fix the first problem, you can introduce another template parameter with a default value of `Char`.  The usual fix to the second problem is to use the `enable_if` expression itself as the template parameter type, instead of a default.  That leaves you with something like this:

```
template <typename C = Char,
          std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<C, char>::value>* = nullptr>
String FromACString(const char* p_src) {
    //...
}

template <typename C = Char,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<C, char>::value>* = nullptr>
String FromACString(const char* p_src) {
    //...
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79ff039704166c17)

Now, depending on how `Char` is defined, you end up with one template with the signature

```
template <typename, void*>
String FromACString(const char*);
```

and another that is ill-formed and therefore disabled by SFINAE.

Answer (score 3):

Miles' answered what's wrong with your `enable_if`. However, you can avoid the nuances of `enable_if` by using `if constexpr`:

```
inline std::basic_string<TCHAR>
FromACString(const char * p_src)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TCHAR, char>) {
        // logic for case where TCHAR is char
    } else {
        // logic for case where TCHAR isn't char
    }
}
```

---

PS. Your TCHAR conversion to `wchar_t` (which I assume is the only other possible type besides `char`) should probably take character encoding into consideration. You might use [mbsrtowcs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbsrtowcs).

Comment: my function is for "abc", but not for u8"z\u00df\u6c34\U0001f34c"