# Why can't we use class templates directly for deducing method templates? SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

This code works:

```
// g++ -std=c++11
// (or)
// clang++ -std=c++11

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct Tester
{
    template <class S = T, class = decltype(S())>
    static void Test (int && k)
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructible" << std::endl;
    }

    static void Test (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Not default constructible" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct HasDefaultConstructor
{
    HasDefaultConstructor() = default;
};

struct NoDefaultConstructor
{
    NoDefaultConstructor() = delete;
};

int main ()
{   
    Tester<HasDefaultConstructor>::Test(int());
    Tester<NoDefaultConstructor>::Test(int());

    return 0;
}
```

But I'd like to understand why I need to set up `S` for the indirect template deduction `template <class S = T, class = decltype(S())>`.

I'd prefer to do it more simply by using `template <class = decltype(T())>`, but in gcc this results in wrong outputs: all calls to the `Test` method go to the first one; and in clang this results in an error `call to deleted constructor of 'NoDefaultConstructor'` (Thanks to HolyBlackCat for pointing out the clang compile error here).

Why? What is the process of the compiler / c++ standard that forces us to indirectly refer to the class templates?

Comment: Current GCC seems to do what you want here (whether that’s *correct* is a separate question).

Comment: @DavisHerring What flags are you using? Mine complies, but incorrectly says that both of the example types have default constructors (I mention this in the question).

Comment: Nothing interesting: just [`-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/djRmVnVq8D7I6vYO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you first instantiate the template class `Tester`. So the requirement `class = decltype(T())` becomes a requirement on the template class `Tester<T>` itself. So if it isn't satisfied the template class is malformed. **Edit**: imagine ypu actually wanted to write a template function with `X` as template parameter and uses `class X = decltype(T())` as default entry? How compiler would tell it apart from SFINAE stuff?

The indirect deduction `template <class S = T, class = decltype(S())>` transforms it into requirement on the template function `Test` instead of the whole class.

This is the technical reason. Yeah, nobody likes SFINEA and function meta programming which is why concepts are being introduced in C++20 and constexpr programming is being developed.

Comment: Your edit is a really good explanation as to why, in both examples, the compiler can’t know that I’d like to SFINAE one of the methods away. Thanks.

Comment: As to why GCC allows `decltype(T())` as a template argument when `T()` is invalid, it's probably a bug. There's a similar bug [#57943](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=57943) for this. Also see [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function).