# How to Check if a Template Type can be Constructed from a Given Type

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to use `std::enable_if_t` to enable a class if the template parameter is any type of `std::string` (bonus points for an answer that shows how to do this with a general string from multiple libraries).

I don't want to have to do "if `Text` is a `const char*`, `std::string`, `std::string_view`, etc." Essentially, I don't want to specifically mention every possible string-like object. All I'm going to do with this object is print it to console, and the `Text` object will be stored as a class attribute.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this than accounting for every individual type?

Comment: Do you want to be able to have a function `print` in your class if the member is `printable` (whatever this means)? This would also include `int`s and other primitive types, but for the purpose of printing to console, `int`s seem very much like strings to me

Comment: @StefanGroth If you look at the first comment on the other answer by ALX23z, I defined exactly what I meant by printable :)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the type_traits library:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

You are probably interested in `is_constructible`, `is_convertible`, or `is_assignable` depending on the exact method you want to use.

For example `is_constructible<T, Args...>` tests if there is a constructor `T::T(Args...)`.

`is_convertible<From, To>` tests if `To` can be converted to `From`: e.g., following code compiles `From Y = (From)X;` where `X` is a `To`

Comment: I did look into this and, funny enough, found out about these after I posted the question. Nevertheless, I think that `std::string_view` is the problem with these. Is there a way to deal with a general "printable" type (meaning a type that is not numeric but can be printed to `std::cout`)?

Comment: @DrakeJohnson I am fairly certain that `std::string_view` is convertible to `std::string`, no?

Comment: It shows `is_convertible` is false from `string_view` to `string`. However, looking at how the STL does it in the `<string>` header, they define a template typedef (of type `_StringViewIsh`) `using _Is_string_view_ish = enable_if_t<conjunction_v<is_convertiable<const _StringViewIsh&, basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits>>, negation<is_convertable<const _StringViewIsh&, const _Elem*>>>>;` The problem is that this is kinda difficult to wrap my head around.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson you can do the other thing - `std::string` is convertible to `std::string_view`. So you can easily write function that converts whatever into the `std::string_view` and prints it - or just tries to print it without attempting to convert (at least make specialization for `const char*`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [is_detected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) for this. We're trying to check whether the given type is printable with one of `std::cout`s overloads of `operator<<` or if the type itself provides an `operator<<` for printing to `std::cout`.  For a more general explanation of how I implemented this, check out https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/06/02/write-template-metaprogramming-expressively/

First, we define an appropriate `is_detected` for the overloads of std::cout itself:

```
// check std::cout.operator<<(T {})
template<typename = void, typename Arg = void> struct test_operator_of_cout : std::false_type {};

template<typename Arg>
struct test_operator_of_cout<std::void_t<decltype(std::cout.operator<<(std::declval<Arg>()))>, Arg>
    : std::true_type {};

template<typename Arg>
constexpr bool test_operator_of_cout_v = test_operator_of_cout<void, Arg>::value;
```

And another one for all overloads of `operator<<(ostream&, T {})`. The link I posted above generalizes this to have less code redundancy.

```
// check operator<<(std::cout, T {})
template<typename = void, typename Arg = void> struct test_operator_of_struct : std::false_type {};

template<typename Arg>
struct test_operator_of_struct<std::void_t<decltype(operator<<(std::cout, std::declval<Arg>()))>, Arg>
    : std::true_type {};

template<typename Arg>
constexpr bool test_operator_of_struct_v = test_operator_of_struct<void, Arg>::value;
```

We can now use these type traits to implement the print function with enable_if:

```
template<typename T> struct MyClass {

    T t;

    template<
        typename Consider = T,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<
            ( test_operator_of_cout_v<Consider> || test_operator_of_struct_v<Consider>) 
            && !std::is_arithmetic_v<Consider>
        >
    > void print() {
        std::cout << t;
    }

};
```

There are two things to note here:

- You need the first template argument of `Consider = T`. Otherwise, the compiler will try to instantiate the declaration of the function, which is ill-formed for types that do not fullfil the condition. Check out this SO-Answer for a more in-depth explanation: [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function)
- Arithmetic types are not printable because of the `!std::is_arithmetic`. I personally would not include this because I do not see a reason why my class shouldn't allow perfectly printable types to be printable.

Now we can look at what is printable and what not:

```
struct NotPrintable {};

struct Printable {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Printable& p) {
         return os;
    }
};

auto foo() {

    MyClass<const char *> chars;
    chars.print(); //compiles

    MyClass<std::string> strings;
    strings.print(); //compiles

    MyClass<std::string_view> string_views;
    string_views.print(); //compiles

    MyClass<Printable> printables;
    printables.print(); // compiles

    // MyClass<int> ints;
    // ints.print(); // Does not compile due to !is_arithmetiv_v

    // MyClass<NotPrintable> not_printable;
    // not_printable.print(); //Does not compile due to operator checking

}
```

You can check out the complete example here: https://godbolt.org/z/ZC9__e