# How to conditionally define a variable in method call using SFINAE?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, sfinae

I want to define a template class `IE` which provides public `method()`. `method()` calls underlying private `run()`, which may take arguments related to template parameters passed to `IE`. So:

- For `IE<void>`, `run()` without arguments is executed.
- For any other T in `IE<T>`, `run(vector<T>)` is executed.

I think I correctly SFINAE'd method `run()`, but I have problem with defining the parameter that should be passed to `run`. I came up with defining `Extra` in the presented way, but I get errors that T can't be deduced.

EDIT: I need a solution working for C++14 at most.

```
template<typename X=void>
class IE
{
    template<typename T=void>
    struct Extra;

    template<typename T>
    struct Extra<enable_if_t<is_void<T>::value, T>> {};

    template<typename T>
    struct Extra<enable_if_t<!is_void<T>::value, T>>
    {
        std::vector<T> ex;
    };

    template<typename X_=X>
    void run(enable_if_t<is_void<X_>::value , Extra<X_>> x) {
        cout << "In run" << endl;
    }

    template<typename X_ = X>
    void run(enable_if_t<!is_void<X_>::value , Extra<X_>> x)
    {
        cout << "In run: X=" << x.ex.size() << endl;
    }

public:
    void method()
    {
        Extra<X> x;
        run(x);
    }
};

int main() {
    IE<double> ie1;
    ie1.method(); // should execute run(vector<double>)

    IE<> ie2;
    ie2.method(); // should execute run()
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From your intent, you can do it with [Constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17). e.g.

```
template<typename X=void>
class IE
{

    void run() {
        cout << "In run()" << endl;
    }

    void run(std::vector<X> x)
    {
        cout << "In run: X=" << x.size() << endl;
    }

public:
    template<typename X_ = X>
    void method()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<X_, void>)
            run();
        else
            run(std::vector<X_>{...});
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Idb9B0dOWM20bpZD)

Before C++17 you can apply SFINAE (or specialization), e.g.

```
template<typename X=void>
class IE
{

    void run() {
        cout << "In run()" << endl;
    }

    void run(std::vector<X> x)
    {
        cout << "In run: X=" << x.size() << endl;
    }

public:
    template<typename X_ = X>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<X_, void>::value> method()
    {
        run();
    }
    template<typename X_ = X>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<X_, void>::value> method()
    {
        run(std::vector<X_>{...});
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JOy3jpePvCaBT9Km)

For your original solution, you should apply SFINAE as

```
template<typename X=void>
class IE
{
    template<typename T, typename = void>
    struct Extra;

    template<typename T>
    struct Extra<T, enable_if_t<is_void<T>::value>> {};

    template<typename T>
    struct Extra<T, enable_if_t<!is_void<T>::value>>
    {
        std::vector<T> ex;
    };

    template<typename X_ = X>
    enable_if_t<is_void<X_>::value> run(Extra<X_> x) {
        cout << "In run" << endl;
    }

    template<typename X_ = X>
    enable_if_t<!is_void<X_>::value> run(Extra<X_> x)
    {
        cout << "In run: X=" << x.ex.size() << endl;
    }

public:
    void method()
    {
        Extra<X> x;
        run(x);
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BK0M7G9Vd1hwy6JE)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am bound to c++14. Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: @PiotrG Answer revised.

Comment: songyuanyao's code shows very nicely how such a thing can be implemented - I like the constexpr approach!
Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function (further explanation).

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I my case, method() is very long, and basically only run() is different. That is why I am using template solution: I wanted single method() and change only the part enclosed in run(). Now with two distinct methods() I don't get any benefit of using templates at all.

Comment: @PiotrG Then can't you simply refactor `method()` into a template parameter agnostic part and a template parameter dependent part?

Comment: @PiotrG Like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oF0uECAqOoE0ahBo)?

Comment: @songyuanyao, yes, that finally works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is your definition of `Extra` which is incorrect,

You might simply move it outside class and use regular specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct Extra
{
    std::vector<T> ex;
};

template<>
struct Extra<void> {};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df9ccfe671fca169)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the actual code is more complicated, but for the code presented in the question, providing a specialization for `IE<void>` is the simplest approach. Get rid of all those `enable_if` things, and after definition of `IE` add the specialization:

```
template <>
class IE<void> {
    void run() { /* ... */ }
public:
    void method() { run(); }
};
```

(Yes, I'm not a fan of using `constexpr if` to write functions that have two or more completely independent execution paths depending on some type calculus; that's far too much like `#ifdef ... #elif ... #endif`)