# How std::enable_if prevents declaration of member template?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, sfinae

*Stroustrup C++ 4th* Ed Page 796 states that

> "If `Enable_if`’s condition evaluates to `false`, the whole function
> declaration of which it is part is completely ignored." and "...we
> don’t declare anything.".

I have also read [this suggested thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function) in which **SFINAE** only works if substitution in argument deduction of a template argument makes the construct ill-formed.

For this example, I am trying to understand how SFINAE omits the `Enable_if<false, T> f0(int x) {};` construct.

Is it because of the lack of a return type `::type` makes the template construct ill-formed language-wise?

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<bool B, typename T>
using Enable_if = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;

struct X 
{
   template <class T>
   Enable_if<false, T> f0(int x) {};
   template <class T>
   Enable_if<true, T> f0(int x) {};
};

int main(void)
{
   X xx;
   xx.f0<void>(0);
   return 0;
}
```

I understand the case in the prior mentioned thread for a construct:

```
template <typename enable_if<false>::type* = nullptr> 
void f0() {}
```

this is because the template parameter is ill-formed (no `::type` to assign `nullptr` to.)

Comment: "Is it because of the lack of a return type ::type makes the template construct ill-formed language-wise? " <- Yes, and the fact that the compiler is allowed to try other functions in the overload set.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to understand how *SFINAE* omits the `Enable_if<false, T> f0(int x) {};` construct. Is it because of the lack of a return type
> `::type` makes the template construct ill-formed language-wise?

Short answer: **NO**!

You need to have a look, how SFNINAE basically works form [a good c++ book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714121). For instance from the [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

> This rule **applies during overload resolution of function
> templates**: When substituting the explicitly specified or deduced
> type for the template parameter fails, the specialization is
> **discarded from the overload set** instead of causing a compile error.

Meaning, you need first of all overloaded template-functions! This has been achieved in the given example code.

Secondly, the part of [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). It checks the condition you provide in

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
//       ^^^^^^^ -----------------------> here!!
struct enable_if;
```

at compile-time and, decide whether [to activate the part below or not](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae#Library_support).

> The standard library component `std::enable_if` allows for creating a
> substitution failure in order to enable or disable particular
> overloads **based on a condition evaluated at compile time**.

In your code, for the given overload

```
template <class T>
Enable_if<false, T> f0(int x) {};
//        ^^^^^ ---------------> CONDITION == false
```

the condition is `false`, and hence in effect, this part (code) will not be there after the compiler done with the compilation.

---

> Is it because of the lack of a return type `::type` makes the template
> construct ill-formed language-wise?

For the reason mentioned above, **NO**; that is not the reason!

By providing a template-type-alias like this

```
template<bool B, typename T>
using Enable_if = typename std::enable_if<B,T>::type;
//                                            ^^^^^^^ --> type has been mentioned here!
```

you have mentioned the `::type` via the alias type `Enable_if</*condition*/, T>`.