# How to restrict generic class method template parameter to certain types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, sfinae, class-template

I have checked out [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function)

However it doesn't work for me. I need to restrict `T` of a class method to some types.

```
template<typename T = typename enable_if_t<
    is_same_v<T, long> || is_same_v<T, int> || is_same_v<T, double> 
    || is_same_v<T, float> || is_same_v<T, size_t>>
    >
shared_ptr<Node<T>> LinkedList<T>::AddNumbers(
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> p1, shared_ptr<Node<T>> p2, T carry)
{
    <snip>
}
```

I get build error:

```
identifier T is undefined
```

I am using C++20. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

---

I try out `concepts` suggested by @JeJo, but get the following build error on the line performing arithmetics:

```
error C2676: binary '/': 'T' does not define this operator or 
a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

I have the template class declaration in header file and implementation in `.cpp` file. Header file:

```
template <typename T> class LinkedList
{
public:
    <snip>
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> AddNumbers(
           shared_ptr<Node<T>>, shared_ptr<Node<T>>, T carry = 0);
};
```

When I use the suggestion by @JeJo, I bump into

```
error C3855: 'LinkedList<T>': template parameter 'T' is
             incompatible with the declaration
```

Comment: If you have C++20, you can just use `requires`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what the other answers say, the member function doesn't need to (and shouldn't) be a template, assuming you use `requires`. That's only necessary when you use the classical SFINAE.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename ...P>
concept one_of = (std::is_same_v<T, P> || ...);

template <typename T>
struct Node {};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> AddNumbers(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>, std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>, T carry = 0)
    requires one_of<T, int, long, std::size_t, float, double>
    {
        // ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> s;
    s.AddNumbers(nullptr, nullptr, 0);

    LinkedList<char> t;
    // t.AddNumbers(nullptr, nullptr, 0);
}
```

Any boolean condition can be spelled after `requires`, but I've added a concept for brevity.

Comment: This solution makes more sense. Don't need to instantiate the template methods.

Comment: The constraint on the member function doesn't make sense to me, which prevents `s.AddNumbers(std::shared_ptr<Node<long>>{}, nullptr, 0)`. If so, why not just constrain the *class* in the first place? IMO the member function *should* be template so that it can accept various arithmetic types.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I agree, not sure why OP wants that.

Comment: What do you mean various arithmetic types? The constraints applied to the method is cascaded down to `Node<T>` member field.