# conditional compilation of void argument member method using enable_if

Tags: template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct MyClass{

  void hello( void) {
    hello(std::is_same<T,bool>());
  }

   void hello(std::true_type){
     cout<<"hello only for bools"<<endl;
   }

};


int main(int argc, char** argv){

  MyClass<bool> myclass1;
  myclass1.hello();

  MyClass<float> myclass2;
  //myclass2.hello(); //throws error as it should

  return 0;
}
```

I wrote the above code after reading [enable_if method specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627651/enable-if-method-specialization/6627748#6627748). I want the hello() method to exist only if template argument is bool and it works. However I am running into problems when I am trying to solve the same problem using enable_if. I have the following code. Any help is appreciated. If enable_if is not appropriate for this job, what is generally used?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct MyClass{

  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,bool>::value, void>::type
  hello(void)
  {
    cout<<"hello only for bools"<<endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  MyClass<bool> myclass1;
  myclass1.hello();

  MyClass<float> myclass2;// compilation error. Don't know how to solve
  //myclass2.hello(); //I want only this line to cause compilation error

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I found the solution to my question in jpihl's answer at [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function). But could anyone explain why the above doesn't work?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct MyClass{

  template<class Q = T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, bool>::value, void>::type hello()
  {
    cout<<"hello only for bools"<<endl;
  }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  MyClass<bool> myclass1;
  myclass1.hello();

  MyClass<float> myclass2;// throws errow. Don't know how to solve
  myclass2.hello(); //

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt with `enable_if` does not work because SFINAE applies in overload resolution
of function (or member function) *templates*, where it will eliminate
a specialization of the function template from the overload set when that
specialization cannot compile.

The member `hello`, in your first attempt, is not a member function *template*.
It has no template parameters. It is simply a member *function* of a *class* template.

Its return type is formulated by an `enable_if` expression that
will provoke compilation failure if the *class* template parameter `T` is not
instantiated as `bool`. This doesn't make the member function itself into a template.
SFINAE has no application. Once you declare `MyClass<float> myclass2`, the
specialization of `MyClass<T>` and all its members is completely determined.
The member function `hello` of that specialization *must* be instantiated,
and with `T` = `float` the attempt to do so must fail to compile.

In the second, successful attempt, `hello` *is* a member function template (of
a class template). It has a template parameter, `Q`, which by default is = `T`.
So SFINAE applies and you can leverage it with `enable_if` in the intended manner.
You may declare `MyClass<float> myclass2` without error, because doing so
does not force any instantiation of the template member `MyClass<float>::hello<Q>`

Since you have written only one overload of `hello`, there is only one specialization
of the member function template for any choice of `Q`. When `Q` = `bool`, that 
single specialization survives and `myclass1.hello()` will
compile. When `Q` != `bool`, SFINAE eliminates the that single specialization
and `myclass2.hello()` does not compile.

To appeciate vividly how SFINAE in the second case is operating at instantation of
the *member function template*, consider that:

```
  MyClass<float> myclass2;
  myclass2.hello<bool>();
```

is fine; while on the other hand:

```
  MyClass<bool> myclass1;
  myclass1.hello<float>();
```

does not compile.

Here is [documentation of SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

Comment: @user2709349 And welcome to Stackoverflow! The way to say thanks for an answer here is to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by ticking the grey check-mark.